# How do I encode URI parameter values?

Tags: java, url, rest, urlencode, rfc2396

I want to send a URI as the value of a query/matrix parameter. Before I can append it to an existing URI, I need to encode it according to RFC 2396. For example, given the input:

`http://google.com/resource?key=value1 & value2`

I expect the output:

`http%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%2fresource%3fkey%3dvalue1%2520%26%2520value2`

Neither `java.net.URLEncoder` nor `java.net.URI` will generate the right output. `URLEncoder` is meant for HTML form encoding which is not the same as RFC 2396. `URI` has no mechanism for encoding a single value at a time so it has no way of knowing that value1 and value2 are part of the same key.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what result do you expect. I would use URLEncoder.

Comment: According to the Javadoc for URL: "The URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for HTML form encoding, which is not the same as the encoding scheme defined in RFC2396."

Comment: @Peter: Agreed, but the latter is dead. There is at least one up-voted answer so it won't show up in the list of unanswered questions even though the answer is technically wrong. If you want to help please go vote it down to zero.

Comment: I wonder what would be result for example you give in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment about this being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304806/encode-and-decode-rfc2396-urls

Comment: @Peter: I added a sample input and output per your request.

Comment: Bugger, Stackoverflow marks a question as answered even if all answers have a score of zero! Please consider voting for http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/103614-use-score-0-instead-of-up-votes-for-unanswered-questions to fix this.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Comment: Is this like this question:  [How to encode URL parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135132/how-to-encode-url-parameters) , except for Java (that one is for JavaScript) ? If yes, java.net.URLEncoder is the (or "a") correct answer.

Comment: @DavidBalažic Wrong, I explicitly mention why `URLEncoder` won't work in the above question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Jersey's [UriBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) encodes URI components using application/x-www-form-urlencoded and RFC 3986 as needed. According to the Javadoc

> Builder methods perform contextual encoding of characters not permitted in the corresponding URI component following the rules of the application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type for query parameters and RFC 3986 for all other components. Note that only characters not permitted in a particular component are subject to encoding so, e.g., a path supplied to one of the path methods may contain matrix parameters or multiple path segments since the separators are legal characters and will not be encoded. Percent encoded values are also recognized where allowed and will not be double encoded.

Comment: URL is unreachable. But http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html is available already

Comment: @sergdev, fixed the link. Thanks for the head's up!

Comment: How exactly did you produce the expected output mentioned above using the UriBuilder? I have no clue how to tell it to encode the part before the "?". Thanks!

Comment: If you are not use JAX-RS and are using Spring you could use Spring's UriUtils

Comment: @tbh, The point I was trying to make is that if you use UriBuilder it'll encode what needs to be encoded for you. If you want to manually encode sections of text it turns out that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304806/encode-and-decode-rfc2396-urls/579167#579167 will work. Alternatively, you can use UriBuilder.fromPath("http://host/").matrixParam("key", "http://google.com/resource?key=value1 & value2").build() and you'll get back "http://host/;key=http:%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fresource%3Fkey%3Dvalue1%20&%20value2".

Comment: Beware of using UriBuilder for "free" URLs that do not use JAX-RS's parameter scheme with curly braces. Even if it might be an exotic value, try this: `UriBuilder.fromPath("http://www.query.example/").queryParam("key", "{val}").build();` will fail. `"http://www.query.example?key=" + URLEncoder.encode("{val}", "UTF-8")` will work.

Comment: @ujay68: UriBuilder treats curly brace as template delimiters. Have you tried `UriBuilder.fromPath("http://www.query.example/").queryParam("key", "{val}").build("{val}")`?

Comment: FYI. If you have a full URL string already, and just care about special characters being replaces appropriately, you can simply just build it like so: UriBuilder.fromPath(urlString).build(); That will encode all the special characters to the right of the first "/" at the end of the hostname of the URL.

Answer (score 20):

You could also use Spring's [UriUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html)

Answer (score 9):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on answers, but I just wanted to note that downloading the JSR-311 api by itself will not work. You need to download the reference implementation ([jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)).

Only downloading the api from the JSR page will give you a ClassNotFoundException when the api tries to look for an implementation at runtime.

Comment: specifically, you need jsr311-api, jersey-server, and jersey-core jars.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my own, it's short, super simple, and you can copy it if you like:
http://www.dmurph.com/2011/01/java-uri-encoder/

Comment: I guess people are hesitant to like this solution because maybe they fear it will have bugs etc.  It looks pretty comprehensive, and has had a couple of bugs addressed already, so I think I will try it out.

Java and Objective C both don't have built in routines to do this kind of encoding, which is just ... baffling

Comment: Hmm, this is for the URI itself and not for the parameters?

Comment: Spaces should be escaped :)  It will only include numbers, letters, and the 'mark' characters as unescaped

Comment: @HerrGrumps What? Obj-C has def had built-in URL encoding for a long time.

Comment: @Jadar oh? ok, maybe I was wrong on Obj-C and/or Java not having it - sorry :)  For reference maybe you can post a reply with some class/method names in the event that it might help someone out who might not know where to look (like me ;) )

Comment: @HerrGrumps Not sure about pure Java, I ended up using Android specific classes. On iOS you can use the `URLComponents` class to break a URL down into its constituent parts and the `queryItems` property to set parameters. But that's outside the scope of this answer and question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [CharEscapers](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/util/common/base/CharEscapers.java) from Google GData-java-client has what you want. It has uriPathEscaper method, uriQueryStringEscaper, and generic uriEscaper. (All return Escaper object which does actual escaping). Apache License.

Comment: Unfortunately it uses some other classes and interfaces, but I think you'll be able to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: "There has to be an easier way than this". It amazes me that this common use-case (building URIs) isn't easier to do. java.net.URI should do a better job.

Comment: I was surprised at how messy this area is (honestly, I didn't even know there is such thing as special URI Encoding ... I learned something).

Comment: Peter, I just realized this might work: https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html

I am using JAX-RS anyway for my application. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Peter, please add the following and I will mark it as the accepted answer:
"
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder will do what you want:

https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html
"

Comment: Feel free to answer your question yourself :-) You found solution which works best for you. People who are searching for same problem can then choose whatever works for them.

Comment: The reason I want you to post the answer is that I can't "accept" my own answer. Please post a new answer and I'll "accept it".

Comment: OK. Didn't know about accepting own answer, I thought it's possible.

Comment: +1 for CharEscapers.  I ran into this issue today and this fixed it:  

// false will force spaces to encode as %20
CharEscapers.uriEscaper(false).escape(value);

Answer (score -2):

I think that the [URI class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) is the one that you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't help because it expects me to pass in a full query string. It has no way of knowing which part of the string needs to be encoded and which part does not. I need a method that takes in a raw parameter value and passes out the URL encoded form.

Comment: Yes. Stackoverflow marks questions as answered if they have been up-voted once. This answer has been up-voted by one person and I down-voted it. It still marks my questions as answered last time I checked.

Comment: My bad.  You're right.  I assumed "upvoted answer" meant ... you know, an answer with a positive number to its left ...

Comment: Same here, please vote for http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/103614-use-score-0-instead-of-up-votes-for-unanswered-questions

Comment: Why don't you update your question to indicate that the URI class will not work for you? Otherwise, someone else will enter in the same advice even if I delete my answer. BTW, why can't the full URI be encoded?

Comment: I will update the question. The reason the full URI can't be encoded is if I pass in "key=value with spaces&still part of value" the constructor has no way of knowing where the value begins and ends.

Answer (score -2):

Mmhh I know you've already discarded URLEncoder, but despite of what the docs say, I decided to give it a try.

You said:

> For example, given an input:
>
> *http://google.com/resource?key=value*
>
> I expect the output:
>
> *http%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%2fresource%3fkey%3dvalue*

So:

```
C:\oreyes\samples\java\URL>type URLEncodeSample.java
import java.net.*;

public class URLEncodeSample {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println( URLEncoder.encode( args[0], "UTF-8" ));
    }
}

C:\oreyes\samples\java\URL>javac URLEncodeSample.java

C:\oreyes\samples\java\URL>java URLEncodeSample "http://google.com/resource?key=value"
http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fresource%3Fkey%3Dvalue
```

As expected.

What would be the problem with this?

Comment: It is similar to RFC2396 but is not the same. For example, try encoding spaces. URLEncoder will encode it as '+', URIs expect %20 instead. There are other differences.

Comment: Ok but you wouldn't be encodgin: "value with space" but "value+with+space" like this:

Comment: like:java URLEncodeSample "http://google.com/resource?key=value+with+spaces" http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fresource%3Fkey%3Dvalue%2Bwith%2Bspaces

Comment: There are a whole slew of rules that one must follow for RFC 2369. Instead of playing games with the input string I'd rather find a class that encodes things properly.

Comment: What do you intend to do? That would be very helpful to know in order to give you the right answer.