# Encoding URL query parameters in Java

Tags: java, urlencode

How does one encode query parameters to go on a url in Java?  I know, this seems like an obvious and already asked question.

There are two subtleties I'm not sure of:

1. Should spaces be encoded on the url as "+" or as "%20"?  In chrome if I type in "http://google.com/foo=?bar me" chrome changes it to be encoded with %20
2. Is it necessary/correct to encode colons ":" as %3B?  Chrome doesn't.

Notes:

- `java.net.URLEncoder.encode` doesn't seem to work, it seems to be for encoding data to be form submitted. For example, it encodes space as `+` instead of `%20`, and encodes colon which isn't necessary.
- `java.net.URI` doesn't encode query parameters

Comment: This question looks useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values

Comment: the structure of the query part is server-dependent, though most expect `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` key/value pairs. See here for more: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/12/java-safe-character-handling-and-url.html

Answer (score 150, accepted):

[`java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String s, String encoding)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) can help too. It follows the HTML form encoding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
```

---

On the other hand, [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (also known as [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) encodes space with `%20`. Colon is a reserved character, so `:` will still remain a colon, after encoding.

Comment: I mentioned that I didn't think that does url encoding, instead it encodes data to be submitted via a form.  comments?

Comment: That's because `URLEncoder` is conformed to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format (which is a valid HTML form encoding). I'm assuming that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Right, so doesn't that disqualify your answer? Or, are you saying its output is still valid, just stricter than necessary?

Comment: @Alex Black, I just updated my comment. I'm assuming you're looking for encoding to conform to URI as specified in RFC2396.

Comment: Btw, if you're using HttpClient 4, you don't need to as HttpClient does it for you.

Comment: Yes, RFC2396 looks like the encoding I want.  It looks to me like URLEncoder.encode is for http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type

Comment: @Elite: I can't ever seem to figure out what you mean :)  Yes, I am using HttpClient 4, so far its not doing it for me.  Are you saying there is a method in it that does?

Comment: No, If you're doing an `HttpGet` then encoding is necessary, but generally, passing parameters with `HttpParams`, HttpClient 4 knows how to encode them.

Comment: I ended up using URLEncoder.encode and replacing "+" with "%20"

Comment: Because one of the (3rd party) sites I am sending HTTP requests to does not decode "+" to " ", but it does decode "%20" to " ".

Comment: It encodes slashes to "%2F", shouldn't it leave the URL slashes as they are?

Comment: @golimar No, it shouldn't. You are supposed to give it parameter value only and not the whole URL. Consider example `http://example.com/?url=http://example.com/?q=c&sort=name`. Should it encode `&sort=name` or not? There is no way to distinguish value from the URL. That is the exact reason why you need value encoding in the first place.

Comment: But actually, slash is a legal character in querystring parameter values.

Answer (score 24):

Unfortunately, URLEncoder.encode() does not produce valid percent-encoding (as specified in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)).

URLEncoder.encode() encodes everything just fine, *except* space is encoded to "+". All the Java URI encoders that I could find only expose public methods to encode the query, fragment, path parts etc. - but don't expose the "raw" encoding. This is unfortunate as fragment and query are allowed to encode space to +, so we don't want to use them. Path is encoded properly but is "normalized" first so we can't use it for 'generic' encoding either.

Best solution I could come up with:

```
return URLEncoder.encode(raw, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
```

If `replaceAll()` is too slow for you, I guess the alternative is to roll your own encoder...

EDIT: I had this code in here first which doesn't encode "?", "&", "=" properly:

```
//don't use - doesn't properly encode "?", "&", "="
new URI(null, null, null, raw, null).toString().substring(1);
```

Comment: `+` is a perfectly valid encoding of a space.

Comment: @LawrenceDol it's true but sometimes `+` may be interpreted incorrectly - take a look at C# https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yangxind/2006/11/08/dont-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding/

Comment: This. I compared various alternatives against Javascript's `encodeURIComponent` method output, and this was the only exact match for the ones I tried (queries with spaces, Turkish and German special characters).

Comment: Ahmet+Mehmet Demir => `Ahmet%2BMehmet+Demir` , According to my understanding the only problem here is MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In such cases space is encoded to `+` char, if the intention was searching two entries in a web form, like google search by a GET request. URI RFC allows `+` char as a valid char. So, it doesn't need to be escaped normally.

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: `URIUtil` is no longer available in more recent versions, better answer at [Java - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198894/java-encode-url/6199056#6199056) or by Mr. Sindi in this thread.

---

[`URIUtil`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html#encodeQuery(java.lang.String)) of Apache httpclient is really useful, although there are some [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

```
URIUtil.encodeQuery(url);
```

> For example, it encodes space as "+" instead of "%20"

Both are [perfectly valid in the right context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20). Although if you really preferred you could issue a string replace.

Comment: I would have to agree.  Use HttpClient, you will be much happier.

Comment: That look promising, got a link by chance? I'm googling but finding many.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to be present in HttpClient 4.1? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIUtils.html

Comment: @Alex, hmm that's annoying, I've always used that routine with good results. One idea is to grab the source code from the 3 release since they now obviously didn't want to maintain it anymore.

Comment: Along time ago I copied the class from the old HTTP commons (and altered it so it was a single class) and put it on gist: https://gist.github.com/agentgt/3011049

Comment: You bet this is annoying. Currently, there is a `URLEncodedUtils.encodeFormFields` which is a private static method. Wouldn't it be reasonable to this method be declared as public?

Comment: `URIUtil.encodeWithinQuery` is what you would use an encode an individual query parameter, which is what the original question seemed to be asking.

Answer (score 11):

It is not necessary to encode a colon as %3B in the query, although doing so is not illegal.

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

It also seems that only percent-encoded spaces are valid, as I doubt that space is an ALPHA or a DIGIT

look to [the URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for more details.

Comment: But doing so can change the meaning of the URI, since the interpretation of the query string is up to the server. If you are producing a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` query string, either is fine. If you are fixing up a URL that the user typed/pasted in, `:` should be left alone.

Comment: @tc. You are right, if colon is being used as a general delimiter (page 12 of the RFC); however, if it is not being used as a general delimiter, then both encodings should resolve identically.

Comment: You also have to be careful as URLs are not really a subset of URI: http://adamgent.com/post/25161273526/urls-are-not-a-subset-of-uris

Comment: A colon is %3A not %3B (thats a semicolon), for anybody who is manually encoding

Answer (score 4):

The built in Java URLEncoder is doing what it's supposed to, and you should use it.

A "+" or "%20" are *both* valid replacements for a space character in a URL. Either one will work.

A ":" *should* be encoded, as it's a separator character. i.e. http://foo or ftp://bar. The fact that a particular browser can handle it when it's not encoded doesn't make it correct. You should encode them.

As a matter of good practice, be sure to use the method that takes a character encoding parameter. UTF-8 is generally used there, but you should supply it explicitly.

```
URLEncoder.encode(yourUrl, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `+` is only a representation of space in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; it is not guaranteed to work even when restricted to HTTP. Similarly, `:` is valid *in a query string* and *should not* be converted to `%3B`; a server can choose to interpret them differently.

Comment: this method also encode whole url slashes and other characters which are part e.g `http://` to `http%3A%2F%2F` which is not correct

Comment: @ToKra you are not supposed to encode the `http://` part. The method is for query parameters and encoded form data. If, however, you wanted to pass the URL of another website as a query parameter, THEN you would want to encode it to avoid confusing the URL parser.

Comment: @tc My reading of https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3 is that all GET form data is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. Doesn't that mean is must work for HTTP?

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add anther way to resolve this problem.

If your project depends on spring web, you can use their utils.

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

UriUtils.encode('vip:104534049:5', StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Output:

```
vip%3A104534049%3A5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String param="2019-07-18 19:29:37";
param="%27"+param.trim().replace(" ", "%20")+"%27";
```

I observed in case of Datetime (Timestamp) 
`URLEncoder.encode(param,"UTF-8")` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The white space character " " is converted into a + sign when using `URLEncoder.encode`. This is opposite to other programming languages like JavaScript which encodes the space character into %20. But it is completely valid as the spaces in query string parameters are represented by +, and not %20. The %20 is generally used to represent spaces in URI itself (the URL part before ?).

Answer (score -3):

if you have only space problem in url. I have used below code and it work fine

```
String url;
URL myUrl = new URL(url.replace(" ","%20"));
```

example : url is

> www.xyz.com?para=hello sir

then output of muUrl is

> www.xyz.com?para=hello%20sir