# Uncaught Syntax Error Unexpected token : , but the server received a valid json object from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, solr

I am trying to do a GET request to **solr** search engine using `$.ajax()` from jQuery. This is the code I am using for doing an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port#/solr/mycore/select?indent=on&q=myparam:value&wt=json',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp : "callback",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Success", data);
            },
            error: function(data) { alert("Error"); }
        });
```

So I am getting a valid json object in the response but somehow the browser throws an `Uncaught Syntax Error`. The actual error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>
> select?indent=on&q=myparam:value&wt=json&callback=…*....somevalue...*

The tricky part is that the response header is `text/plain` when I checked in the browser. How can I solve this? Please help me...

Comment: It seems the server is not sending back valid JSONP. JSON is not the same as JSONP. I guess this is a duplicate of [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7936610/218196)

Comment: Check if any of your single/double quotes are messed up in the HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved. Actually I had to use `jsonpCallback:"mysuccesscallbackfunction"` in the ajax call and `json.wrf=mysuccesscallbackfunction` in the URL. It looks like this now:

```
$.ajax({
url : 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port#/solr/mycore/select?indent=on&q=myparam:value&wt=json&json.wrf=mysuccesscallbackfunction',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp : "callback",
        jsonpCallback:"mysuccesscallbackfunction",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Success", data);
        },
        error: function(data) { alert("Error"); }
    });
```

and my `mysuccesscallbackfunction` is:

```
function mysuccesscallbackfunction(resp) {
        console.log('inside mysuccesscallbackfunction: ', resp );
    }
```

Now, first it executes whatever is inside `mysuccesscallbackfunction` and then goes to default `success` callback. I found it somewhere on web. I would still like to know why it worked now.

Answer (score 0):

[Colons require encoding in query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713671/do-colons-require-encoding-in-uri-query-parameters).

Your url should look like this:

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port#/solr/mycore/select?indent=on&q=myparam%3Avalue&wt=json`

If you're generating the query string dynamically, use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to correctly encode special characters.

Comment: If that was the issue, the OP wouldn't receive a response from the server or would they?

Comment: using `encodeURIComponent()` didn't help :( @Flix Kling