# PL/SQL UTL_HTTP.REQUEST - Curly Braces/Semicolon

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call a URL using the UTL_HTTP package in Oracle Autonomous Database and getting an ORA-06512:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1810
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 144
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1745
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

All network ACLS etc. are configured correctly.

The URL in question requires JSON directly in the URL which I understand is bad practice, however I don't have control over the API. If I remove the curly braces ( {} ) and semicolons ( : ), the request using UTL_HTTP works but the output is incorrect as the JSON becomes invalid.

I've tried encoding the URL using an online encoder as well as the UTL_URL.ESCAPE function, which gives the same error as above.

The encoding from UTL_URL.ESCAPE IS:

An example of the URL format is:

```
https://example.com/rest.php?entity=contact&action=get&json={"name": "Lorum Ipsum", "end_date": {"IS NULL": 1}, "return": "id,contact_id"}
```

I've tried a straight select using utl_http.request:

```
SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://example.com/rest.php?entity=contact&action=get&json={"name": "Lorum Ipsum", "end_date": {"IS NULL": 1}, "return": "id,contact_id"}') FROM DUAL;
```

And calling using PL/SQL:

```
declare
    req UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    resp UTL_HTTP.RESP;
    val VARCHAR2(2000);
    str varchar2(1000);
begin
    req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('https://example.com/rest.php?entity=contact&action=get&json={"name": "Lorum Ipsum", "end_date": {"IS NULL": 1}, "return": "id,contact_id"}');
    resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
    LOOP
        UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp, val, TRUE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(val);
    END LOOP;
UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY
THEN
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;

/
```

How do I call this url using UTL_HTTP?

Comment: please edit the question and show the relevant pl/sql code.  thanks

Comment: edited to show both the SQL and PL/SQL tried.

Comment: How did you try encoding the URL? Using `utl_url.escape` or some other function? Could you show the output?

Comment: @kfinity 
I've edited the original question with more information on the encoding. I can't provide the exact output from the actual URL as it contains data, but the example url comes out with the same hex encodings for URLs.


`https://example.com/rest.php?entity=contact&action=get&json=%7B%22name%22:%20%22Lorum%20Ipsum%22,%20%22end_date%22:%20%7B%22IS%20NULL%22:%201%7D,%20%22return%22:%20%22id,contact_id%22%7D`


I have just noticed the colons aren't getting encoded by the UTL_URL package which could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They talk about this a bit in the [UTL_URL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_URL.html), but colons are reserved characters - they're valid in some parts of a URL, but not in others. (Curly braces are not allowed at all.) There's [been some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713671/do-colons-require-encoding-in-uri-query-parameters) about whether or not they're valid in the Query portion of a URL - the ABNF in the RFC seems to say yes, but a lot of implementations don't allow it.

By default, `UTL_URL.ESCAPE` doesn't escape reserved characters (because that would screw up the `https://` part, etc), but you can change that by passing TRUE as the second argument. In general, best practice seems to be escaping reserved characters in any query string that might contain them:

```
req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('https://example.com/rest.php?entity=contact&action=get&json=' 
       || utl_url.escape('{"name": "Lorum Ipsum", "end_date": {"IS NULL": 1}, "return": "id,contact_id"}'
            ,TRUE));
```

See if that helps?

Comment: This fixes the issue. The documentation does state that it won't escape colons, for good reason as you pointed out. Using a concatenation like you did, or using the replacing the colons with %3A. Your solution is more elegant. Thanks!