# sending a second query parameter to a servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, query-string

In my web-app the client pings the server *(tries to contact a ping servlet on the server)* wheere the address / resource locator of the servlet is :

```
"192.168.43.187/server/ping?" + new ClientAddress().getNetworkIP();
```

Till now the client has been sending it's network IP to the server with every ping. I wanted to add another piece of information with this URL,which is `new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();` .

How do I send *this* along ?

***Note :***

In the URL, ***ping*** is a servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would construct the URL thus:

```
"192.168.43.187/server/ping?ip=" + (new ClientAddress().getNetworkIP()) + "&time=" + (new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
```

and use the servlet request method [ServletRequest.getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to extract the values.

Note that [ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) gives you the client address. Do you need to pass it explicitly ? Additionally, constructing a URL by string concatenation works in this trivial scenario, but as soon as you pass values that include characters such as spaces etc. you'll need to [encode these values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

```
"192.168.43.187/server/ping?ip=" + new ClientAddress().getNetworkIP() + 
    "&time=" + new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();
```

You will need to change "ping" servlet in order to read those parameters.