# POST String as parameter in Url

Tags: java, android, foursquare

I am testing foursquare api. Here is the url.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?venueId=123&shout=Test&broadcast=public,twitter,facebook&oauth_token=something
```

the problem is when I add `shout="test"`. It works fine. But `"test message"` isn't working. I mean `test[space]message` isn't working.I tried with removing spaces,it worked.But,that can't be solution. How can I handle such thing I mean how can I send post request with `shout="test messgae" with space include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using shout="test%20message"

%20 is just HTML code for a space

This is another post found on Stack Overflow that provides more detail [Encoding URL Query Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java)

Comment: Correct! You might add info about needing to encode values in query string values in URLs, and perhaps what code could be used to do that.