# Replace spaces with %20 in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I am pushing some variables to a `httpGet` statement and it is failing on any spaces, how can I replace the spaces in the variable with `%20` prior to running the GET?

---

I am trying to encode "felton, ca" which is in the variable `from` with `def fromFormatted = URLEncoder.encode(from, "UTF-8")`

and when I run the code I get the error

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.net.URLEncoder.encode() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray, java.lang.String) values: [[felton, ca], UTF-8]`

original input field

```
section("Departing From:"){
    input "from", "text", title: "Address?"
```

---

Also tried `def fromFormatted = from.encodeAsURL()`

with the result of

`%5B%22felton%22%2C%22ca%22%5D`

---

apparently since the input text contained a `,` then it automatically treated that input text as an array. Any thoughts on keeping this from happening, or converting it to a string and maintaining the comma?

---

I resolved the array by using `def fromStr = from.join(",")`

unforunately `join` creates a json string that adds double quotes

`%22felton%22%2C%22ca%22`

Is there another method for joining the array that would maintain the comma without adding quotes?

Comment: You need to url encode the string. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java for details

Comment: I tried `def fromFormatted = URLEncoder.encode(from, "UTF-8")` and get error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.net.URLEncoder.encode() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray, java.lang.String) values: [[felton, ca], UTF-8]`

Comment: add code to the questions. Its difficult to guess otherwise. Based on the error, It looks like "from" variable is a `List` and not a string.

Comment: You are passing a `JSONArray` where `URLEncoder.encode()` requires a `String`.

Comment: strange..considering the input field is just `text`. how can i convert this field to a plain string?

Comment: The `from` field does not look like it is coming from a text field as part of normal form submit.  You have something else in the mix here that will explain why `from` is a JSONArray.

Comment: Even if your call to encode worked, I think you are going to get a `+` and not `%20` in place of the space.  The same thing you would get from calling `from.encodeAsURL()`.

Comment: ya i tried `from.encodeAsURL()` and it encoded the brackets and quotes.`%5B%22felton%22%2C%22ca%22%5D` I need to convert this array to a string somehow.

Comment: Can you add the actual implementation to the question what is being tried yet?