# ASCII to Hex-Java

Tags: java, hex, ascii

I have no information about tranform ASCII to hex String. I looked ASCII table in the link [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). However I have really no idea how I can implement this?

ASCII in JSON file:

```
{ "number": 7,
          "planning": [
            [5,0,[],"2015-11-26 09:00:36",null,["england",2150.4,0,86400,2,1,0,"brighton","holiday"]]
           ]
        }
```

Hex:

```
"%7B%20%22number%22%3A%207%2C%0A%20%20%22planning%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C0%2C%5B%5D%2C%222015-11-26%2009%3A00%3A36%22%2Cnull%2C%5B%22england%22%2C2150.4%2C0%2C86400%2C2%2C1%2C0%2C%22brighton%22%2C%22holiday%22%5D%5D%0A%20%20%20%5D%0A%7D"
```

For me every ASCII is meaningful but what is the %. Is it escape character?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Taka a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Comment: Implement what? %xx is an escape character to represent an ASCII character using its hex representation. So %7B is asci character 0x7B, (123 in decimal) which is the "{" character, etc.

Comment: It means that the hex number that comes after represents one character

Comment: @TDD Thank you. So somehow I completely  wrote my question wrong. I expected to transform String into the URL encoding/Percent-encoding.

Comment: All ASCII characters are ASCII encoded already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the [*percent-encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (also known as URI/URL encoding). As you can read on the wiki page, URI/URL only allows a small set of characters. In order to represent others, one uses a percentage (`%`) followed by the ASCII-code. The percentage symbol is encoded as well (since otherwise it would make the language ambiguous).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330150/67579) addresses several ways how you can encode this. You can for instance use:

[`URIUtil.encodeQuery(url);`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html#encodeQuery(java.lang.String))