# Missing character "+" in the return value of Request Parameter Map in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-encoding, http-request-parameters

I am trying to get parameters from an URL in my JSF application. The URL as following: `http://localhost:8088/*******/pages/rh/evaluation/layouts/evaluationLayout.jsf?crt_affectId=RqI+dgtx6q8=`

So here the parameter is `crt_affectId` and its value is `RqI+dgtx6q8=`. 
When I try to get the value by using the following code:

```
String cryptedValue = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getRequestParameterValuesMap().get(cryptedKey)[0];
```

I get the wanted value but missing the character `+` as it is replaced by a blank space as . the result value is as following: `RqI dgtx6q8=`.

Is there a solution in JSF to get the complete value or a should I just replace the blank space by the "+"? However this latter is not that generic and good way neither.

Comment: Your URL should be encoded in *UTF-8*. Perhaps you could first [set your character encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#setRequestCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)) and then retrieve the value you want. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/1346996) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5330239/1346996) answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` is URL-encoded representation of the space. So the behavior is correct. Those parameters should have been URL-encoded beforehand.

If you have full control over those parameters, then you can URL-encode the individual parameter values as below before passing it to e.g. `ExternalContext#redirect()`.

```
String url = "/evaluationLayout.jsf?crt_affectId=" + URLEncoder.encode("RqI+dgtx6q8=", "UTF-8");
ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + url);
```

In case you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), it can be done more conveniently as its [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) utility already transparently takes care of this.

```
Faces.redirect("/evaluationLayout.jsf?crt_affectId=%s", "RqI+dgtx6q8=");
```

#### See also:

- [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)