# JMeter - How do i pass DOB in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to pass a date in dd/mm/yyyy format with POST request in Jmeter.
When i pass dob parameter as 21/11/2011 in my request then final request become -

```
dob=21%2F11%2F2011&
```

How I will make my date as below -

```
dob=21/11/2011&
```

Below is my Jmeter snapshot -
[image]

I also unchecked and checked the 'encode?' option but nothing happens. Its takes %2f.

Comment: are you passing the date using querystring?

Comment: I am passing the date normally via CSV and also tried using dob=21/11/2011 in parameter request.

Comment: What I mean is is that querystring parameter or form parameter? If its a querystring one, you should be OK with it, The application you are testing should be able to handle it.

Comment: I am not sure what querystring is. I have uploaded the jmeter snap shot and passing date as normal text dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Is it causing the application to break? because the screenshot you added looks OK and the application should be able to handle it. That is a standard behavior... @Md.ZishanPaya

Comment: No tried the webservice using postman and application behave perfect. But with request '/' is replaced by %2f in jmeter which is creating problem with my request and not getting proper response.
I also used UTF-8 in content encoding but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

basically the value is  encoded i.e., "/" is getting replaced by %2F. use content encoding text box in http sampler value to appropriate hence it will not encode.

refer the below

[Encoding URL query parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. How to use content encoding?

Answer (score 0):

[reference screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlPKj.png)  This the place i mentioned to set the content encoding. if you dont set any by default what you have set must go as it is i.e., "/" as "/" only , by chance in any place content encoding is to some other value (eg: "UTF-8" ) then the setter will do its job , i.e., converting "/" to %2F

Comment: un check the encode in your initial screen and try.

Comment: I also used UTF-8 in content encoding but no luck.
I don't understand why my post request parameter having '/' converted to %2f even after hard-coding under value or fetching date from CSV.

Comment: try this way  1. with no Encode? [the pic you attached]checked and no content encoding provided  2. No Encode? and provide content encoding as UTF-8     3rd  like wise take ..since i dont have a case to work for you but wanted to give solution

Answer (score 0):

Add a pre processor script as child to HTTP sampler and try adding the below code

```
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("dob","12/12/12","=")
```

Note: Make sure in your http sampler, you have not added "dob" argument , here we are adding dob progrmatically, so only one place dob should exist that is in script only.

i hope this should work.