# send bold & italic text on telegram bot with html

Tags: html, sendmessage, telegram, telegram-bot

I've created a bot in telegram

I want to send bold and italic text with HTML page to bot

My HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head><title>Telegram</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="https://api.telegram.org/bot(token)/sendMessage">
        <input type="hidden" name="chat_id" value="@testadminch">
        <input type="hidden" name="parse_mod" value="markdown">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I send `*bold*` the output should be **bold** but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure putting your token inside a form?

Comment: 1. You have a typo: parse_modE. 2. You shouldn't use such code on public websites, because any client visiting a website downloads its HTML source code, so everybody will see your telegram bot token

Comment: A detail blog: http://sforsuresh.in/telegram-bot-message-formatting

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To send **bold**:

1. Set the [`parse_mode`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) to `markdown` and send `*bold*`
2. Set the [`parse_mode`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) to `html` and send `<b>bold</b>`

To send *italic*:

1. Set the [`parse_mode`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) to `markdown` and send `_italic_`
2. Set the [`parse_mode`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) to `html` and send `<i>italic</i>`

Comment: what about underlined text for markdown parsing please?

Comment: @MuradAlm. these are the formatting options supported by telegram: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Comment: To make it less abstract: sendMessage(userid, message, { parse_mode: "HTML" });

Answer (score 35):

If you are using PHP you can use this, and I'm sure it's almost similar in other languages as well

```
$WebsiteURL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$BotToken;
$text = "<b>This</b> <i>is some Text</i>";
$Update = file_get_contents($WebsiteURL."/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=$text&parse_mode=html);

echo $Update;
```

Here is the list of all tags that you can use

```
<b>bold</b>
<strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>
<em>italic</em>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
```

Comment: @Mo. it does work only if you set the parse mode into "html".

Comment: @MarcoConcas That is correct, as these are HTML tags!

Answer (score 11):

According to [the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) you can set the `parse_mode` field to:

- **MarkdownV2**
- **HTML**

The *Markdown* mode still works but it's now considered a *legacy* one. Use *MarkdownV2* instead.

You can pass the `parse_mode` parameter like this:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[yourBotKey]/sendMessage?chat_id=[yourChatId]&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=[yourMessage]
```

For bold and italic using MarkdownV2:

```
*bold text*
_italic text_
```

And for HTML:

```
<b>bold</b> or <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</I> or <em>italic</em>
```

Make sure to encode your query-string parameters regardless the format you pick. For example:

- Java/Scala (see [note on spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java)):

```
val message = "*bold text*";
val encodedMsg = URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
```

- Javascript ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent))

```
var message = "*bold text*"
var encodedMsg = encodeURIComponent(message)
```

- PHP ([ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php))

```
$message = "*bold text*";
$encodedMsg = urlencode($message);
```

Answer (score 5):

So when sending the message to telegram you use:

```
$token = <Enter Your Token Here>
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

$chat_id = <The Chat Id Goes Here>;
$test = <Message goes Here>;

//sending Message normally without styling
$response = file_get_content($url."\sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=$text");
```

If our message has html tags in it we add "parse_mode" so that our url becomes:

```
$response = file_get_content($url."\sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=$text&parse_mode=html")
```

parse mode can be "HTML" or "markdown"

Answer (score 3):

To Send bold,italic,fixed width code you can use this :

```
# Sending a HTML formatted message
bot.send_message(chat_id=@yourchannelname, 
             text="*boldtext* _italictext_ `fixed width font` [link]   (http://google.com).", 
             parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

make sure you have enabled the bot as your admin .Then only it can send message

Comment: what library to install for this? `python-telegram-bot` ? that didn't work.

Comment: pip install python-telegram-bot

Comment: This works for me even today,try again if you have problem then I will tell version

Comment: perhaps it depends on how you access the API. i was using `api.telegram.org/bot<api token>/"sendMessage?<different methods>`. hence `parse_mode=MARKDOWN&chat_id={}&text={}".format(chat_id, msg)` in the method worked for me when posting the message.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have all options from [core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style)

```
<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<u>underline</u>, <ins>underline</ins>
<s>strikethrough</s>, <strike>strikethrough</strike>, <del>strikethrough</del>
<span class="tg-spoiler">spoiler</span>, <tg-spoiler>spoiler</tg-spoiler>
<b>bold <i>italic bold <s>italic bold strikethrough <span class="tg-spoiler">italic bold strikethrough spoiler</span></s> <u>underline italic bold</u></i> bold</b>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
<pre><code class="language-python">pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language</code></pre>
```

And the result looks like:
[image: results_telegram]

Answer (score 2):

For italic you can use the 'i' tag, for bold try the 'b' tag

```html
    <i> italic </i>
    <b> bold </b>
```

Comment: please read this page:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style

Comment: It shows both html mode, and markdown mode. Since the first option wasn't working for you I suggested the other one 

"To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field when using sendMessage. The following tags are currently supported:

<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<a href="URL">inline URL</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>"

Comment: i change parse_mod to HTML and i send `<b>bold</b>
<bold>bold</bold>`

output is: `<b>bold</b>
<bold>bold</bold>`

i want output is **bold**

Answer (score 0):

`For JS:`

First, if you haven't installed telegram bot just install with the command

```
npm i messaging-api-telegram
```

Now, initialize its client with

```
const client = new TelegramClient({
    accessToken: process.env.<TELEGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN>
});
```

Then, to send message use sendMessage() async function like below -

```
    const resp = await client.sendMessage(chatId, msg, {
        disableWebPagePreview: false,
        disableNotification: false,
        parseMode: "HTML"
    });
```

Here parse mode by default would be plain text but with parseOptions parseMode we can do 1. "HTML" and "MARKDOWN" to let use send messages in stylish way. Also get your access token of bot from telegram page and chatId or group chat Id from same.