# How can I use HTML markup in Watson Assistant through Node-RED?

Tags: html, telegram, telegram-bot, watson, watson-conversation

I'm studying chatbots and I want to use rich media in my responses. 
Things like images, buttons and links. 
But I'm having a real hard time doing so, I've searched here on STack and found one interesting article: 
[send bold & italic text on telegram bot with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119481/send-bold-italic-text-on-telegram-bot-with-html). But I can't find the option "parse_mode" that was mentioned there. 
If anyone has any idea please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the nodes of

- https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-telegrambot
- https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-watson

In that case I think (I have no experience with the telegram bot nodes) your flow might start from

1. *telegram receiver* to
2. *a node preparing the conversation context for watson assistant* to
3. *watson conversation* to
4. *node processing the watson conversation output (intent,...) and converting it to input for the telegram sender node* to
5. *telegram sender node*

I don't know the kind of input the *telegram sender node* could accept, but if it is possible to specify html markup content then you can construct the respective html markup content in step 4 (you can consider using the *template* node for this).

See also https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-watson-chatbot-on-nodered/

I hope this helps. If not please specify some more details.
Jan.

Comment: Good morning Jan, thanks for answering and your willingness to help. 
I used the tutorial in the third link (https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-watson-chatbot-on-nodered/) to make the integration between the Watson Assistant chatbot and the Telegram platform. 
I will check out the two articles you recommended, I hope they have the information I need or put me in the right direction. 

Best regards, 
Rogerio Rodrigues.