# Use bold tag to send my message from node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to use Bold tag example: `<b>Hiii</b>` to send my messages to user on running of node server.

I am using : `npm Tgfancy`

## Node

```js
const chatId = '-xxxxxx';

const token = '566470572:ffffff';

const bot = new Tgfancy(token, {
    // all options to 'tgfancy' MUST be placed under the
    // 'tgfancy' key, as shown below
    tgfancy: {
        option: "value",
    },
});

bot.sendMessage(parse_mode='HTML', chatId, replyText);
```

How can I parse HTML with that?

I have my content but its not tagging with bold or any other HTML tags.

## My code

```js
var replyText = " Signal #"+coinName+ " has reached 1st target! " +profit+ "% profit \nCurrent Price:" +liveCoinPrice+ "\nDuration: " +difference + "\nNote: Message from live coin high node server";
```

Here, I want to bold `coinName`, `profit`, etc.

## Output

[image]

Any help would be thankful.

Comment: how do you output your html? How do you handle response from above? Can you provide more details, additional code?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what you are doing with this string.

Comment: @Quentin I just want to bold those fonts on telegram message.

Comment: You might have wanted to lead with the fact you were dealing with telegram.

Comment: check my output,

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119481/send-bold-italic-text-on-telegram-bot-with-html

Comment: @Quentin . its not worked

Comment: @TanmoySarkar — Where's the code where you set the parse mode? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: _“i tried . its not worked”_ - please realize that this is one of the worst responses you could possibly give, and avoid them in the future. If you already tried something that worked for other people, then you need to show us how exactly you tried to use it if you are still having trouble it. Just saying “did not work” is just BS.

Comment: @CBroe sure i will keep it on mind.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar This link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119481/send-bold-italic-text-on-telegram-bot-with-html has the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for `parse_mode = "HTML"`.

> https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/108

```js
var replyText = "Signal #" + coinName.bold() + " has reached 2nd target! " + profit.bold() + "% profit \nCurrent Price: " + liveCoinPrice.bold() + "\nDuration: " + difference.bold();

var option = {
  "parse_mode": "HTML",
};

bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, replyText, option);
```