# Make the name variable appear bold in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a chat app built using HTML, Javascript, Node.js and Socket.io. I want the name of the user that is stored in data.name to appear bold. I tried adding * to the start and end of the variable but it only added asterisk as a text.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
socket.on('receive', data => {
  var msger = `${data.message}`;
  console.log(msger.length);
  if (name.length == 0) {
    append(`Anonymous: ${data.message}`, 'left');
  } else {
    append(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`, 'left');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question, not in an external image.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Use bold tag to send my message from node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379281)

Comment: Please show the code for the `append()` method.  What does it do?  Where is this text being displayed?  If it's being displayed in a browser, then you will want to wrap it in the HTML tag `<b>Your text</b>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the bold() method on that variable. This should wrap the text in a bold tag and then return it

```
` ${data.name.bold()} `
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you might be able to get away with just wrapping it in a b tag.

```
` <b> ${data.name} </b> `
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as follows.

```
append(`<strong>${data.name}</strong>: ${data.message}`, 'left');
```

This way name is written in bold.