# Send Telegram bot messages with formatted text

Tags: request, telegram-bot

I am sending Telegram bot messages in the following way:

```
bot_message = "Hi **James**, how are you doing?"

send_text = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&parse_mode=Markdown&text={bot_message}"

response = requests.get(send_text)
```

However, it seems like I'm not able to correctly format **bold** content within the message; how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [send bold & italic text on telegram bot with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119481/send-bold-italic-text-on-telegram-bot-with-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one `*` instead of two as detailed in the [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options).