# Why is Jersey's UriBuilder.build method encoding #'s and %'s, but not /'s?

Tags: rest, jersey, urlencode, jax-rs

I have a REST API which is fairly typical, except that the id's of resources are not integers, but strings, which often contain `/` characters. So if a customer's id is `string/with/slashes` then the URI for that customer should be `http://localhost/customers/string%2Fwith%2Fslashes`. When returning a list of customers, I want to construct that URI with a [UriBuilder](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/p/javax.ws.rs.core/c/UriBuilder) so I can put it in the href of ATOM-style link elements. But it doesn't quite work; here's a small test class that shows what I mean:

```
@Path("/customers")
public class JerseyTest {

  @Path("{id}")
  public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("{id}") String id) {
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    buildURI("string#with#hashes"); // => http://localhost/customers/string%23with%23hashes
    buildURI("string/with/slashes"); // => http://localhost/customers/string/with/slashes
  }

  public static void buildURI(String id) {
    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost");
    builder.path(JerseyTest.class).path(JerseyTest.class, "getCustomer");
    URI uri = builder.build(id);
    System.out.println(uri);
  }
}
```

The `#`'s get encoded as I would expect but the `/`'s don't. I tried using `builder.build(URLEncoder.encode(id))` instead, but then the UriBuilder encodes the `%`'s so you get `.../string%252Fwith%252Fslashes`!

It seems inconsistent to me that it encodes `#` and `%` but not `/`, but I suspect there is a good reason for it which I am not seeing. So my question is:

1. How can I get UriBuilder to give me `.../string%2Fwith%2Fslashes`, which is the URI that causes Jersey to call `getCustomer` with `id` equal to `string/with/slashes`? **edit**: I discovered a way to solve this: `builder.buildFromEncoded(URLEncoder.encode(id))`. Leaving this question open though, in hopes of getting an answer to the second part...
2. More generally, why does `UriBuilder.build` encode some special characters, but not others?

I found [How do I encode URI parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values), where the accepted answer says "Use UriBuilder." Well, I am using it, but apparently I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but what happens when you use the unicode escaped value: `buildURI("string\u002fwith\u002fslashes")`?

Comment: For info, `URI.toString` method modifies the address. `URI.getPath` don't. Take a look at `com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriComponent.encode(s, t)`, the transformation to `%7...` is done there. `/` are part of the URI, so, maybe, there is way to escape them. (I keep digging)

Comment: @stand I'm pretty sure `"string\u002fwith\u002fslashes"` compiles to exactly the same bytecode as `"string/with/slashes"` but it's worth a try. So I tried it; same output. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @yves I found a solution for part 1 and edited it into the question. Let me know if you find anything related to part 2 though!

Comment: The downside of URLEncoder is that it replaces spaces with plus ("foo bar" -> "foo+bar"), where you would expect %20 ("foo bar" -> "foo%20bar")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seem to be a confirmed issue:

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-70

Your workaround sounds good.

Comment: Good find. "According to the Jersey team this is not a bug in Jersey but it is wanted by the JAX-RS specification, because they tried to fix it but noticed that the TCK enforces this weird behaviour." :(