# How to encode URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, url, encodeuricomponent

I am trying to pass parameters to a URL which looks like this:

```
http://www.foobar.com/foo?imageurl=
```

And I want to pass the parameters such as an image URL which is generated itself by another API, and the link for the image turns out as:

```
http://www.image.com/?username=unknown&password=unknown
```

However, when I try to use the URL:

```
http://www.foobar.com/foo?imageurl=http://www.image.com/?username=unknown&password=unknown
```

It doesn't work.

I have also tried using `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` on the imageURL, and that too doesn't work.

Comment: What language is generating the URL? JavaScript?

Comment: Note that you should not put passwords in urls, not even when using https, as every router between client and server will see the whole url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create query parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111529/how-to-create-query-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: @fabb That doesn't seem to be true: https://stackoverflow.com/a/499594/513038

Comment: @Erhannis GET path and params are encrypted for HTTPS, but not HTTP (which, ok, no-one should be using, but still...). However, much more seriously, server logs and any analytics tools will see the GET params, so you'll log plaintext passwords in your apache logs, and in your Google Analytics. They're also sent through the referrer header, if that's enabled. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233795/are-url-parameters-of-get-and-post-requests-over-https-secure

Answer (score 221, accepted):

**With PHP**

```
echo urlencode("http://www.image.com/?username=unknown&password=unknown");
```

Result

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.image.com%2F%3Fusername%3Dunknown%26password%3Dunknown
```

**With Javascript:**

```
var myUrl = "http://www.image.com/?username=unknown&password=unknown";
var encodedURL= "http://www.foobar.com/foo?imageurl=" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpv53/

Comment: This question is not about PHP, but about Javascript.

Answer (score 65):

Using new ES6 `Object.entries()`, it makes for a fun little nested `map`/`join`:

```js
const encodeGetParams = p => 
  Object.entries(p).map(kv => kv.map(encodeURIComponent).join("=")).join("&");

const params = {
  user: "María Rodríguez",
  awesome: true,
  awesomeness: 64,
  "ZOMG+&=*(": "*^%*GMOZ"
};

console.log("https://example.com/endpoint?" + encodeGetParams(params))
```

Comment: This works very well in my case I added a call to decodeURIComponent inside the map function to make sure entries already encoded dont get messi

Answer (score 34):

With [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams()
params.set('imageurl', 'http://www.image.com/?username=unknown&password=unknown')
return `http://www.foobar.com/foo?${params.toString()}`
```

Comment: Will this work in all browsers and browser versions?

Comment: @PlsWork : while it's a standard, some <1%-browsers have not implemented it: https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams

Comment: Why not use the entirety of the [`URL` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) and start with `const url = new URL("http://www.foobar.com/foo");`? Also, in most circumstances you want [`set`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set), not [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append): `url.set("imageurl", "http://www.image.com/?username=unknown&password=unknown"); return url;`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: good point about set vs append, thanks. Using URL might distract from the main point, since setting the params does not seem to be elegant. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: @serv-inc Depends on the use case; using `URL` itself was just a general suggestion. I prefer to have my URLs always validated by the URL API, even if they’re static, so it might be a bit of an overkill; it’s just preference.

Comment: Or simply: `http://foobar.com/foo?${new URLSearchParams({ imageurl: '...' }).toString()}`

Answer (score 10):

Just try `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` yourself...

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#$%^&*'));
```

Input: `@#$%^&*`.  Output: `%40%23%24%25%5E%26*`.  So, wait, what happened to `*`?  Why wasn't this converted?  TLDR: You actually want [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).  Long-story...

You should not be using `encodeURIComponent()` or `encodeURI()`.  You should use [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), according to the MDN Documentation.

Regarding ***`encodeURI()`***...

> If one wishes to follow the more recent RFC3986 for URLs, which makes square brackets reserved (for IPv6) and thus not encoded when forming something which could be part of a URL (such as a host), the following code snippet may help:

> `function fixedEncodeURI(str) { return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']'); }`

Regarding ***`encodeURIComponent()`***...

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:

> `function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) { return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) { return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); }); }`

So, what is the difference?  `fixedEncodeURI()` and `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` convert the same set of values, but `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` also converts this set: `+@?=:*#;,$&`.  This set is used in `GET` parameters (`&`, `+`, etc.), anchor tags (`#`), wildcard tags (`*`), email/username parts (`@`), etc..

**For example --** If you use `encodeURI()`, `user@example.com/?email=me@home` will not properly send the second `@` to the server, except for your browser handling the compatibility (as Chrome naturally does often).

Comment: What do you mean by `"except for your browser handling the compatibility"`?

Comment: @Stephan: For example, if `site.com?formula=a+b=c` works in producing `formula=>a+b=c`, that violates the spec, but if it works, it's because Chrome/etc. can detect the spec failure of the URL, etc., and so on, w/ `user@site.com?email=user@site.com`.