# special characters in querystring became space while invoking axios post

Tags: javascript, http

My codes will send one **Http-Post** to backend server with one token which may contains one `+` sign.

```
  instance.post('/Handler.ashx', {
    email
  }, {
    params: {
      action: 'QueryUser',
      token: 'KALYh+KnLmH2vpn8ewOfQ3le3zmFr3Jo0jiIOID9fM1%2FCUBV1ULKc4Scq7Io0yA1'
    }
  })
```

But I found the backend received wrong token value. I checked the browser console, then found `+` is replaced with one space.

Below is the requests (POST and OPTIONS due to CORS, backend already set up allow-origin correctly):

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44323/Handler.ashx?action=QueryUser&token=KALYh+KnLmH2vpn8ewOfQ3le3zmFr3Jo0jiIOID9fM1%2FCUBV1ULKc4Scq7Io0yA1
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:44323
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
action: QueryUser
token: KALYh KnLmH2vpn8ewOfQ3le3zmFr3Jo0jiIOID9fM1/CUBV1ULKc4Scq7Io0yA1

Request URL: https://localhost:44323/Handler.ashx?action=QueryUser&token=KALYh+KnLmH2vpn8ewOfQ3le3zmFr3Jo0jiIOID9fM1%2FCUBV1ULKc4Scq7Io0yA1
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: [::1]:44323
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
action: QueryUser
token: KALYh+KnLmH2vpn8ewOfQ3le3zmFr3Jo0jiIOID9fM1%2FCUBV1ULKc4Scq7Io0yA1
```

You will see the `+` is in querystring of the requested URL, but is replaced with the space in `OPTIONS -> token` which **actually the backend received**.

Anyone knows what is wrong? Appreciate it.

Below is the screenshot for browser->console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, inside the query string the `+` is used to represent a space. You'd need to encode it as `%2B`.

Comment: you may notice http-post has correct token value, and http-options not. and axios should encode the querystring value automatically. If I manually change it, axios will escape `%` and the backend will receive `%2B` instead of `+`.

Comment: @Sphinx then something else is double-encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all characters in the URL params can be passed as is and some characters are automatically changed. For a more in deep explanation you can take a look in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and a more detailed solution can be found in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135132/how-to-encode-url-parameters).

```
instance.post('/Handler.ashx', {
    email
  }, {
    params: {
      action: 'QueryUser',
      token: encodeURIComponent('KALYh+KnLmH2vpn8ewOfQ3le3zmFr3Jo0jiIOID9fM1%2FCUBV1ULKc4Scq7Io0yA1')
    }
  })
```