# How do filter records by using dynamic value into URL parameters in web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerapps, webapi

I need to update filtered records from dataverse table by using web api in power pages. But there is a issue to use dynamic value into url parameter in web api. email is the dynamic value.

```js
url: "/_api/cr1d7_userotps?$select=otp_code,cr1d7_isactive,cr1d7_email&$filter=cr1d7_email eq '" & email & "'"
```

I tried this code, but it not working to filter, please support thanks.

I need to filter records by dynamic value.

Comment: URL parameters cannot have the space character in them. In general, use encodeURIComponent for parameters: [How to encode URL parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135132/how-to-encode-url-parameters)