How to use javascript variables in URL as querystring parameters
I want to use javascript variables in URL as querystring parameters. what is correct way?
 var fromSemester = document.getElementById('<%= newFromSemesterValue.ClientID%>').value;
 var toSemester = document.getElementById('<%= newToSemesterValue.ClientID%>').value;

I wan to use fromSemester and toSemester variables in URL as querystring parameters like below: But javascript throws en error. What is the correct way to use VAR variables inside URL?
var url = 'MyPage.aspx?id=2&fromsemester='fromSemester'&tosemester='toSemester'&language=eng'

But this URL is not working

Not working how? Remember to include text in URLs they must be encoded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135132/how-to-encode-url-parameters

You haven't concatenated your strings correctly.

@evolutionxbox It's not about encoding, it's about the proper syntax to concatenate variables. Although encoding could be a problem if there are special characters in the variables.

How I concatenate, this is the question.. I tried many ways with single quote, double quote and backticks but nothing works.

Your example uses single quotes, but you neglected to use the concatenation operator, '+. If you wish to use backticks, then you need to use ${variableName}.

There are several options; the simplest is probably to use the URL class:
const url = new URL('MyPage.aspx?id=2&language=eng', location.href);
url.searchParams.set("fromsemester", fromSemester);
url.searchParams.set("tosemester", toSemester);

Alternatively, string interpolation:
const url = `MyPage.aspx?id=2&fromsemester=${encodeURIComponent(fromSemester)}&tosemester=${encodeURIComponent(toSemester)}&language=eng`;

Or as a last resort, string concatenation:
const url = 'MyPage.aspx?id=2&fromsemester=' 
    + encodeURIComponent(fromSemester) 
    + '&tosemester=' 
    + encodeURIComponent(toSemester) 
    + '&language=eng';


There is also new URLSearchParams(paramsString) See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

works like a charm.. Thanks.
