# If URL paramater value contains unencoded '&' character

Tags: java, web-applications

I am working on a Java web application. This application receives URL parameters from 3rd party's app. Therefore, value of the URL parameter may not be encoded. How do I parse the URL parameter value when parameter value contains unencoded '&' (encode value %26)?

For example:
 "page.jsp?title=Street **&** Smith&address=1223"

Here, 3rd party passed unencoded parameter value: 'Street **&** Smith'

Thanks
 M.F.H

Answer (score 1):

you can't, that's a broken URL (which is why encoding exists in the first place).

you could write some heuristics to "guess" as the the original intent, but it will be a guess (and will be wrong sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another Stackoverflow post from a User who was looking to accomplish similar encoding of parameter values as you are attempting to do: [How do I encode URI parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values)