# Encode content part of URL in Java

Tags: java, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a URL string with replaceable values:

```
  http://DOMAIN:PORT/sendmsg?user=test&passwd=test00&text={CONTENT}
```

I have to encode the content part, so I tried this:

```
  String tempContent = URLEncoder.encode(content, "UTF-8");
```

tempContent had this value: This+is+test+one
I do not want the + where spaces is. Spaces MUST be represented by %20

Now, I can do this:

```
  String tempContent = content.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

BUT that only covers the spaces and I don't have control over the content input.
Is there any other efficient way to encode URL content in Java? URLEncoder does not
do what I want.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: maybe a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work, I used

```
  URIUtil.encodeQuery(url);
```

Correctly encoded spaces with %20. This comes from the Apache commons-httpclient project.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a library which expands URI templates (this is RFC 6570). I know of [at least one](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) (disclaimer: this is mine).

Using this library, you can do this:

```
final URITemplate template
    = new URITemplate("http://DOMAIN:PORT/sendmsg?user=test&passwd=test00&text={CONTENT}");

final VariableValue value = new ScalarValue(content);

final Map<String, VariableValue> vars = new HashMap<String, VariableValue>();
vars.put("CONTENT", value);

// Obtain expanded template
final String s = template.expand(vars);

// Now build a URL out of it
```

Maps are allowed as values (this is a `MapValue` in my implementation; the RFC calls these "associative arrays"), so for instance, if you had a map with (correctly filled) entries for `user`, `passwd` and `text`, you could write your template as:

```
http://DOMAIN:PORT/sendmsg{?parameters*}
```

With a map value `parameters` containing:

```
"user": "john",
"passwd": "doe",
"content": "Hello World!"
```

this would expand as:

```
http://DOMAIN:PORT/sendmsg?user=john&passwd=doe&content=Hello%20World%21
```