# IllegalArgumentException caught when parsing URL with JSON String

Tags: java, url, uri, illegalargumentexception

I need to formulate a url with JSON data that will look something like

http://someurl.com/passfail?parameter={"data1":"123456789","data2":"123456789"}, and I will need to pass it using JBoss's ClientResponse to get a response status.
I first tried passing in the literal String data in

```
ClientRequest clientrequest = new ClientRequest("http://someurl.com/passfail?parameter={\"data1\":\"123456789\",\"data2\":\"123456789\"});// assuming the "\" is formulated correctly
```

but it gives an exception.
Thus I also tried using URL url = new URL(the url) but it doesn't work as well.

I have the following exception caught trying and am feeling pretty stucked and am hoping if anyone could help.

IllegalArgumentException:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriBuilderImpl.buildFromMap(UriBuilderImpl.java:408)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriBuilderImpl.buildFromValues(UriBuilderImpl.java:558)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriBuilderImpl.build(UriBuilderImpl.java:539)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.getUri(ClientRequest.java:786)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.execute(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:77)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:39)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.execute(AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.java:40)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:473)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:704)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.get(ClientRequest.java:509)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.get(ClientRequest.java:537)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:505)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:251)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet JSP
weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:505)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:251)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:505)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:251)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)> 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at line personal Servlet   
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3498)> 
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)> 
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)> 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)> 
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)> 
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)> 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> 
java.net.URI.create(URI.java:842)> 
org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriBuilderImpl.buildFromMap(UriBuilderImpl.java:404)> 
... 60 more> 
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query index 77: http://someurl.com/passfail?parameter={"data1":"123456789","data2":"123456789"}> 
java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)> 
java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)> 
java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3072)> 
java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)> 
java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)> 
java.net.URI.create(URI.java:840)> 
... 61 more>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing illegal characters in your URI string:[Java - Convert String to valid URI object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object)

`http://someurl.com/passfail?parameter={"data1":"123456789","data2":"123456789"}>`

You need to "escape" the offending characters in your URI.

Here are some alternatives:

- [How should I escape strings in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json)
- [Java - Convert String to valid URI object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573184/java-convert-string-to-valid-uri-object)
- [How do I encode URI parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values)
- [Encoding URL query parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

and, last but not least:

- [java.net.URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/jav/net/URLEncoder.html)

PS: what about that ">" in your URL?

Comment: Hi paul, nope it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks paul,

I've read through and do another round of research for this and I was using

```
String url ="http://someurl.com/passfail?parameter={"data1":"123456789","data2":"123456789"}";
String encodedURL = URIUtil.encodeQuery(url);
```

and it gave me status 200, which is a success.

The API I used was from **org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil**.