# Java: Embed One URL in Another

Tags: java, url

I have a url I need to include in another. So far I have:

```
String urlString = "http://company.com/action?sourceUrl=http://stackoverflow.com/foo"
URL url = new URL(urlString);
```

How can I make sure this url does not get messed up? I mean for example, what if I need another parameter:

```
String urlString = "http://company.com/action?sourceUrl=http://stackoverflow.com/foo&count=1"
URL url = new URL(urlString);
```

This is now ambiguous.  Does count belong to the outer URL, or inner?  How do I solve this situation, and in general up one URL in another and then issue the request in Java?

Comment: Encode the source URL parameter with URLEncoder....

Comment: You will need to encode the 2nd URL. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values