# is there any way we can encode the special character and other character in URL for UTF-8, without changing in tomcat configuration

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Can anyone please help me with this:
is there any other way that we can encode the special character and other characters in `UTF-8` in java jsp page, without changing tomcat configuration.

I have used `URLEncoder.encode()` to encode the url in my jsp file and also in my application, but i don't want to make changes in tomcat configuration as my server is continuously running and i can't stop it, so is there any other way we can encode the url without changing the tomcat configuration...

Answer (score 0):

use java.net.URI instead
[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)
OR use URIBuilder [How do I encode URI parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values)
hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add `UTF-8` in encoding.

Use it

```
 URLEncoder.encode(stringToBeEncoded, "UTF-8");
```

instead of

```
URLEncoder.encode();
```

In your jsp, use page charset to UTF-8.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
```

In your servlet, you can use it

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
```

### Resource Link:

[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

---

### UPDATE:

**Use filter from this link:**

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html

> How to use UTF-8 everywhere?

Using UTF-8 as your character encoding for everything is a safe bet. This should work for pretty much every situation.

**In order to completely switch to using UTF-8, you need to make the following changes:**

1. Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" on your `<Connector>` in server.xml.
   References: [HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html), [AJP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html).
2. Use a [character encoding filter](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3) with the default encoding set
   to UTF-8
3. Change all your JSPs to include charset name in their contentType.
   For example, use `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`
   for the usual JSP pages and `<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
   for the pages in XML
   syntax (aka JSP Documents).
4. Change all your servlets to set the content type for responses and
   to include charset name in the content type to be UTF-8. Use
   `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")` or
   `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`.
5. Change any content-generation libraries you use (Velocity,
   Freemarker, etc.) to use UTF-8 and to specify UTF-8 in the content
   type of the responses that they generate.
6. Disable any valves or filters that may read request parameters
   before your character encoding filter or jsp page has a chance to
   set the encoding to UTF-8. For more information see
   http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg21117.html.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have already made changes as URLEncoder.encode(StringToBeEncoded,"UTF-8"); but i don't want to make change in tomcat server.xml Connector as URIEncoding="UTF-8",please suggest me other solution...

Comment: @Akshay Would you please explain why you not want to change tomcat config?

Comment: @Akshay in your jsp, use <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>

Comment: used it already, and i don't want to use it in tomcat because the server is continuously running and , i can't stop it ,to make the changes...

Comment: is there any problem to stop the tomcat server? is it in production? @Akshay

Comment: on that case, you can use a filter in your project web.xml

Comment: @Akshay I have updated the answer given filter link and best use of getting UTF-8 procedure. Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have updated this also in my project web.xml , however it is encoding with special characters like "+ ,space, * " etc., but it is not encoding suppose the german character like "Ö,ß,ä" etc...any solution for this...

Comment: Would you please post your web.xml? @Akshay

Comment: <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
 
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: if  you use specific German, then i got a link which states to use `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>` in jsp. Please have a try http://allinoneissues.blogspot.jp/2012/05/german-characters-encoding-issue.html

Comment: not specific with german characters, want to encode all the character including the german and the rest...

Comment: You just change in your specific jsp page `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>`

Comment: @Akshay Have you changed your servlet for request and response as `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");`