# How to find out if string has already been URL encoded?

Tags: java, utf-8, url-encoding

How could I check if string has already been encoded?

For example, if I encode `TEST==`, I get `TEST%3D%3D`. If I again encode last string, I get `TEST%253D%253D`, I would have to know before doing that if it is already encoded...

I have encoded parameters saved, and I need to search for them. I don't know for input parameters, what will they be - encoded or not, so I have to know if I have to encode or decode them before search.

Comment: Agree.  You have accepted a wrong answer.

Comment: import java.net.URI

String url = "www.demo.demo/demo file not encoded.jpg"
boolean isEncoded = true;
try {
 URI x = new URI(url)
}
catch(Exception ex) {
 isEncoded = false;
}

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Decode, compare to original. If it does differ, original is encoded. If it doesn't differ, original isn't encoded. But still it says nothing about whether the newly decoded version isn't still encoded. A good task for recursion.

I hope one can't write a quine in urlencode, or this algorithm would get stuck.

Exception: When a string contains "+" character url decoder replaces it with a space even though the string is not url encoded

Comment: You gave me the idea, how to do this. Now my SQL looks like `SELECT * FROM something WHERE param= " + param + " OR param = "+encode(param)`

Comment: How do you know that you don't need ``SELECT * FROM something WHERE param= " + param + " OR param = "+encode(param) + " OR param = "+encode(encode(param))``?

That way lies infinite regress.

Comment: well, true except of a case where "good enough" is enough; if the 0.01% of users really want the program not to work, it won't work for them. Sometimes the extra, extreme clauses are just not worth the effort and the overhead.

Comment: This fails if your string contains windows variable names like `%DESCRIPTION%` which decodes to `ÞSCRIPTION%` or `%ABOUT%` which becomes `«OUT%`.

Comment: @benrifkah: true but then there is no way to tell them apart if the input is completely arbitrary.

Comment: @SF. Indeed. I posted the caveat to expose the issue so that people could act according to their needs.

Comment: @SF. : This will fail if the initial unencoded string contains a + character in the middle. The decoded string will contain a space character instead and it will not be equal. A better way would be to compare the lengths. If the original string is larger than the decoded string, then the original was encoded.

Comment: @SF. : But my attempt above also doesn't say anything about whether the newly decoded version isn't encoded as well.

Comment: It doesn't work if the raw string contains a plus sign. You decode it, compare to the original, and the strings are different. The + has been replaced with space. You end up not encoding it, even though you should.

Comment: You sir, saved me in a moment, when my brain has stopped and couldn't figure the following before reading your comment

if( contactNumber != Uri.encode(contactNumber)){
    contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
}

Comment: This is worng. When a string contains "+" character url decoder replaces it with a space even though the string is not url encoded.  see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: This doesn't logically work if using java.net.URLDecode.decode(String, String) implementation. Reason: If the string contains "%xy" where x is a letter, such as "s".  If you try to decode such an unencoded string, it results in throwing IllegalArgumentException("URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - negative value").

Comment: Actually, the logic of attempting to "decode" something that you have not passed through some filter logic is always just a bad design.  This bad design encourages more bad design, such as choosing to try and catch all "Throwable" exceptions and ignore them.  Doing that adds time to process and then ignore exceptions, or worse, hide an exception that could have been useful in diagnosing a real problem.  Just bad, very bad.  ;-)

Comment: Does not work if url contains any query parameters with encoded urls inside. Like log-in links with redirect info inside or query params

Comment: This fails on urls containing none BASIC_LATIN characters too.

Answer (score 20):

Use regexp to check if your string contains illegal characters (i.e. characters which cannot be found in URL-encoded string, like whitespace).

Comment: I did not do this, but this is the solution.

Comment: So how will you differentiate between `hello%20world` and `interest20%growth` ? The first is a valid urlencoded string, the other is a string that has to be escaped and does not produce a valid unescape.

Comment: Checking for illegal characters does not include the percent symbol because it is not illegal it just gets escaped. When you check for the percent symbol you *may* have a URI encoded string if it is followed by "25". This only works if you know that your input is either not encoded or encoded exactly 1 time *and* that the input does not naturally include sequences that URI encoding generates.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was NOT the solution. I'm passing a URL as the url encrypted string, so I did an REFind(':', str) and it returns 6 (https:) whether the string is encrypted or not.

Comment: If a string contains invalid chars, you can prove it is not encoded, but if it contains only valid chars and percent signs, that does not prove that it is encoded.  That is not knowable.  So this may be as good a check as one can realistically do.

Answer (score 5):

Try decoding the url. If the resulting string is shorter than the original then the original URL was already encoded, else you can safely encode it (either it is not encoded, or even post encoding the url stays as is, so encoding again will not result in a wrong url). Below is sample pseudo (inspired by ruby) code:

```
# Returns encoded URL for any given URL after determining whether it is already encoded or not
    def escape(url)
      unescaped_url = URI.unescape(url)
      if (unescaped_url.length < url.length)
        return url
      else
        return URI.escape(url)
      end
    end
```

Comment: this won't work if the url is encoded in the way that a `' '`(space) is replaced by a `'+'` because the length then stays the same

Comment: Probably it's better to encode your URLs only as %20. The pros are described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602/762747

If that's not a possibility, then may be you can check for + signs after ?, and if you find any, then the URL is already encoded and you can return it as is. It's just an extra check to the above code, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know for sure, unless your strings conform to a certain pattern, or you keep track of your strings. As you noted by yourself, a String that is encoded can also be encoded, so you can't be 100% sure by looking at the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check your URL for suspicious characters[1]. 
List of candidates:

`WHITE_SPACE ,", < , > , { , } , | , \ , ^ , ~ , [ , ] , .` and `

I use:

```
private static boolean isAlreadyEncoded(String passedUrl) {
        boolean isEncoded = true;
        if (passedUrl.matches(".*[\\ \"\\<\\>\\{\\}|\\\\^~\\[\\]].*")) {
                isEncoded = false;
        }
        return isEncoded;
}
```

For the actual encoding I proceed with:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796882/1485527

**Note**: Even if your URL doesn't contain unsafe characters you might want to apply, e.g. Punnycode encoding to the host name. So there is still much space for additional checks.

---

[1] A list of candidates can be found in the section "unsafe" of the [URL spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) at Page 2.
In my understanding '%' or '#' should be left out in the encoding check, since these characters can occur in encoded URLs as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring UriComponentsBuilder:

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

private URI getProperlyEncodedUri(String uriString) {
    try {
        return URI.create(uriString);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uriString).build().toUri();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, confirming, it works as expected in Java with spring

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but here's a really simple answer for anyone looking -

1. Decode the original string into a new string.
2. Re-encode the new string.
3. In the re-encoded string, convert '+' to '%20'. This is required based on the language which is doing the conversion because some conversions convert spaces to '+' instead of '%20'. The decode in these situations converts '%20' to space but retains '+' as is.
4. Compare the re-encoded new string with the original string. If they are not equal then the original string was never encoded to begin with.
5. Make sure to handle exceptions for non-decodable strings which will throw an exception instead of decoding.

E.g. -

1. An input ":" will decode as ":" and on re-encoding will become "%3A". "%3A" != ":" and so the original was not encoded.
2. An input "%3A" will decode as ":" and on re-encoding will become "%3A". "%3A" == "%3A" and so the original was encoded.
3. An input "A" will decode as "A" and on re-encoding will become "A". "A" == "A" and so the original string was encoded.
4. An input "%s" will cause an exception on attempting to be decoded. This would need to be handled as a non-decodable string.
5. An input "%3A " will decode as ": " and on re-encoding will become "%3A+", string sanitization will make this "%3A%20". "%3A%20" != "%3A " and so the original was not encoded.
6. An input "%3A%20" will decode as ": " and on re-encoding will become "%3A+", string sanitization will make this "%3A%20". "%3A%20" == "%3A%20" and so the original was encoded.
7. An input "%3A+" will decode as ":+" and on re-encoding will become "%3A%2B". "%3A+" != "%3A%2B" and so the original was not encoded.
8. An input "%3A%2B" will decode as ":+" and on re-encoding will become "%3A%2B". "%3A%2B" == "%3A%2B" and so the original was encoded.

Golang example -

```
originalString := ":"
unescapedString, err := url.QueryUnescape(originalString)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Unable to unescape.")
} else {
    if originalString != strings.Replace(url.QueryEscape(originalString), "+", "%20", -1) {
        fmt.Println("originalString is not escaped.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("originalString is escaped.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be sure that string is encoded correctly (if it needs to be encoded) - just decode and encode it once again.

metacode:

```
100%_correctly_encoded_string = encode(decode(input_string))
```

already encoded string will remain untouched. Unencoded string will be encoded. String with only url-allowed characters will remain untouched too.

Comment: Nope.  Test it with an unencoded string containing "%s" in it.  The exception will make code designed like this fail to execute due to InvalidArgumentException that is caused by an invalid "%xy" where xy are supposed to be hex digits.  Same problem as the accepted answer, and one that tempts additional poor design flaws, such as ignoring unknown exception types.

Answer (score -1):

According to the spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) all URLs *MUST* start with a scheme followed by a :

Since colons are required as the delimiter between a scheme and the rest of the URI, any string that contains a colon is not encoded.

(This assumes you will not be given an incomplete URI with no scheme.)

So you can test if the string contains a colon, if not, urldecode it, and if that string contains a colon, the original string was url encoded, if not, check if the strings are different and if so, urldecode again and if not, it is not a valid URI.

You can make this loop simpler if you know what schemes you can expect.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295286/6371926) I coded a function (JS Language) that encodes the URL just once with `encodeURI` so you can call it to make sure is encoded just once and you don't need to know if the URL is already encoded.

ES6:

```
var getUrlEncoded = sURL => {
    if (decodeURI(sURL) === sURL) return encodeURI(sURL)
    return getUrlEncoded(decodeURI(sURL))
}
```

Pre ES6:

```
var getUrlEncoded = function(sURL) {
    if (decodeURI(sURL) === sURL) return encodeURI(sURL)
    return getUrlEncoded(decodeURI(sURL))
}
```

Here are some tests so you can see the URL is only **encoded once**:

```
getUrlEncoded("https://example.com/media/Screenshot27 UI Home.jpg")
//"https://example.com/media/Screenshot27%20UI%20Home.jpg"
getUrlEncoded(encodeURI("https://example.com/media/Screenshot27 UI Home.jpg"))
//"https://example.com/media/Screenshot27%20UI%20Home.jpg"
getUrlEncoded(encodeURI(encodeURI("https://example.com/media/Screenshot27 UI Home.jpg")))
//"https://example.com/media/Screenshot27%20UI%20Home.jpg"
getUrlEncoded(decodeURI("https://example.com/media/Screenshot27 UI Home.jpg"))
//"https://example.com/media/Screenshot27%20UI%20Home.jpg"
getUrlEncoded(decodeURI(decodeURI("https://example.com/media/Screenshot27 UI Home.jpg")))
//"https://example.com/media/Screenshot27%20UI%20Home.jpg"
```