# Sum symbol in POST

Tags: apache, http, post, sum

I send to my sever this POST petition:
name=pepito&friends=pep+mar

And I notice what arrives is
name=pepito&friends=pep mar

Why sum symbol disappears?
Than you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **+** sign is one way to represent spaces in URLs. The other would be **%20**. There has been a question describing this: [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20)

If you want to send a plus, you have to properly encode it with **%2B**.

Read up on allowed characters in URLs and URLEncode functions.