# PayPal Invoicing API Requests - Formatting

Tags: curl, paypal

Can someone explain to me the significance of "+" and "-" in these string values in PayPal's example? The PayPal docs really don't explain this in the API document.

```
&invoice.itemList.item(0).name=Banana+Leaf+--+001 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).description=Banana+Leaf
```

I see that some values are URL encoded and others have these "+" and "-" characters instead of URL encoding.

Why?

Thanks

```
############################################################
// CreateAndSendInvoice HTTP headers (-H)
############################################################
curl -s --insecure
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: caller_UID"     // UserID from the Caller account
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: caller_PSWD"  // Password from the Caller account
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: caller_Sig"  // Signature from the Caller account
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: XML" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: XML" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T"    // Sandbox AppID
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/CreateAndSendInvoice -d
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US 
&invoice.merchantEmail=merchant%40domain.com 
&invoice.payerEmail=jbui-us-business2%40paypal.com 
&invoice.currencyCode=USD 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).name=Banana+Leaf+--+001 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).description=Banana+Leaf 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).quantity=1 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).unitPrice=1 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).taxName=Tax1 
&invoice.itemList.item(0).taxRate=10.25 
&invoice.paymentTerms=Net10 
&invoice.logoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FYour_logo.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `-` symbol does not need to be URL encoded. In fact if you look at the URL for this page you see `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626956/paypal-invoicing-api-requests-formatting` with plenty of `-` symbols in there.

Secondly, a space can be represented by either `+` or `%20` depending on where it is in the URL. Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602/1408717):

```
+ means a space only in application/x-www-form-encoded content,
such as the query part of a URL:

http://www.example.com/path/foo+bar/path?query+name=query+value

In this URL, the parameter name is 'query name' (with a space) and
the value is 'query value' (with a space), but the folder name in
the path is literally foo+bar, not 'foo bar'.
```

So with your examples, `Banana+Leaf+--+001` translates to `Banana Leaf -- 001` and
`Banana+Leaf` translates to `Banana Leaf`.