# Zend Framework removes chars from get parameters?

Tags: php, zend-framework, get

Does Zend Framework hijack the raw `$_GET` and remove chars? I can't figure out whats going on with a script I am writing.

right now I am passing a variable "email" via a param in the url. Which its working, however. Its stripping out a character and leaving a space.

trying it like `$_GET['email']` or like `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); $params['email']` on an email string that has a `+` in it the `+` gets removed and is replaced with a space. Yet I'm not applying anything that would cause that, that I am aware of anywhere.

So, does anyone else know what the issue may be?

Comment: this is a url encoding issue. A raw + sign in a URL will be taken out if not encoded properly. It has nothing to do with Zend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php does that, see this question:
[When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20)

To get a "+" use %2B in the url

Comment: ...and to get a real + sign use %2B

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: right, my %20 didn't make sense as + is a space too. I changed it to %2B in the answer.

Comment: Wow, well.. all these years coding, and I never knew that one. How in the world did I ever manage to get by without hitting this bump before. So this initially steams from the browser down into the server side script as I understand it from that link? Is there anyway to circumvent/suppress that behavior? Cause what I have is a DB that stores these emails that we have, and I can picture someone hand typing it into the URL and landing me in a bit of a spot there.

Comment: I don't think so, that's the way it works. Google for something containing spaces and you'll see the + in the url