# Parsing string to add to URL-encoded URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the string:

```
"Hello there world"
```

how can I create a URL-encoded string like this:

```
"Hello%20there%20world"
```

I would also like to know what to do if the string has other symbols too, like:

```
"hello there: world, how are you"
```

What would is the easiest way to do so? I was going to parse and then build some code for that.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

In 2019, URI.encode is obsolete and should not be used.

---

```
require 'uri'

URI.encode("Hello there world")
#=> "Hello%20there%20world"
URI.encode("hello there: world, how are you")
#=> "hello%20there:%20world,%20how%20are%20you"

URI.decode("Hello%20there%20world")
#=> "Hello there world"
```

Comment: If you also want to encode dots: `URI.encode('api.example.com', /\W/)`

Comment: Doesn't work, e.g. `URI.encode("http://google.com") => "http://google.com"`. Better use `CGI.escape` (`"https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com"`)

Comment: undefined method `encode' for module URI

Answer (score 34):

While the current answer says to utilize `URI.encode` that has been deprecated and obsolete since Ruby 1.9.2. It is better to utilize `CGI.escape` or `ERB::Util.url_encode`.

Comment: This answer is correct. CGI.escape("www.foo.com/more/here") works now. Key difference is slash's "/", semicolons ":" and array notation "[" "]" started encoding. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

If anyone is interested, the newest way to do this is doing in ERB:

```
    <%= u "Hello World !" %>
```

This will render:

> Hello%20World%20%21

**u** is short for **url_encode**

You can find the docs [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.8.7/ERB/Util:url_encode)

Answer (score 20):

Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) is useful for this. You can build the entire URL programmatically and add the query parameters using that class, and it'll handle the encoding for you:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://foo.com')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(
  's' => "Hello there world"
)
uri.to_s # => "http://foo.com?s=Hello+there+world"
```

The examples are useful:

```
URI.encode_www_form([["q", "ruby"], ["lang", "en"]])
#=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form("q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en")
#=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form("q" => ["ruby", "perl"], "lang" => "en")
#=> "q=ruby&q=perl&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form([["q", "ruby"], ["q", "perl"], ["lang", "en"]])
#=> "q=ruby&q=perl&lang=en"
```

These links might also be useful:

- [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20)
- [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20?rq=1)
- [17.13.4 Form content types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) from the W3's "Forms in HTML documents" recommendations.

Comment: How can i embed the require 'uri' into the html.erb? Or must I put it into the controller?

Comment: The right thing to do, any time there is more than trivial logic needed, is to do all the "computin'" in the controller.

Comment: Cool. When should we be using helpers? And what if we do computing that would be used in many places in the helper and include for the controllers. Does it matter?