# URI.parse doesn't want to parse uri with | (pipe) char

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to send get request with:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

...

uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/#{event_id}?access_token=#{access_token}"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
uri = URI.parse(uri)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
http.use_ssl = true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     response = http.request(request)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
response.body
```

Facebook sent me an `acces_token` with `|` char, and because of it `uri = URI.parse(uri)` throws an error: `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?) https:/ ....`

Is there any other parser, or should I manually extract these host, port, request_uri values? What's the best way of fixing it?

`access_token` looks like `141112112181111|9Alz3xW7P0CQ_DRomJN2oMeiwXs`

`event_id` is for example `385101904985590`

edit: just realized that it's structure is `APP_ID|some_token`

Comment: Can you post an anonymized version of the contents of `access_token`, also `event_id` so we can get a full sense of what you have there? You may need to encode `access_token`.

Comment: The parser is correct in rejecting this URI, and switching to another parser won't help: `|` is illegal in a URI. Period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried encoding the URI with `URI#encode`?

```
uri = 'http://foobar.com?foo=something|weird'    
uri = URI.encode(uri)
uri = URI.parse(uri) => #<URI::HTTP:0x007fe2f48775b0 URL:http://foobar.com?foo=something%7Cweird>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to inject variables into URI query parameters, especially tokens and keys and such as that's a good route to creating an invalid one. Instead, rely on the URI class and let it handle as much as possible.

```
require 'uri'

event_id = 1
access_token = 'foo|bar'

uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/#{event_id}")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(['access_token', access_token])
uri.to_s # => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1?access_token&foo%7Cbar"
```

If you want something more full-featured, [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) is very nice.

See "[Parsing string to add to URL-encoded URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375947/parsing-string-to-add-to-url-encoded-url/17376300#17376300)" for more information.