# HTML action changes spaces into plusses

Tags: javascript, html

A rookie question:

I have a simple submission form, the problem is if there is any space given for the inputs the value gets changed to a plus(+).

This is my form:

```
<form name="input" action="search" method="get">
Web Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
Search Query: <input type="text" name="query"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I'd like to give an example:

if user fills "address here" to the first box and "query here" to the second box. The address that I get after the click is `"search?address=address+here&query=query+here"` instead of `"search?address=address%20here&query=query%20here"`. How can I change these "namespaces" with `%20` instead of + signs?

The reason why I don't want plus sign instead of `%20` is because I am writing a search engine in Java language and using sun's httpserver library for the web server. This library handles the "query" part of the result(which is after? sign) by using `.getRequestURI().getQuery()` method, however this method handles %20 as space and sees plus sign as plus. If this is not "fixable" then I can also accept a solution that involves javascript.

Comment: It's urlencoded and shouldn't matter … browsers will decode the value again.

Comment: It isn't urlencoded, it is form-urlencoded, which is subtly different (the `+` instead of `%20` is the only difference I'm aware of though). **Browsers** will not decode the value. Any form processing library should though.

Comment: I am using this information in Java, unfortunately it does matter in my case as this is not a browser question.

Comment: @SarpKaya — How are you using it in Java? What functions are you using to read the query string?

Comment: @Quentin I wrote the detailed reason now

Comment: @SarpKaya — Please provide more code. How are you reading the query string?

Comment: @Quentin with .getRequestURI().getQuery() method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37814/discussion-between-sarp-kaya-and-quentin)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634271, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2678551

Answer (score -1):

The encoding of the space symbol into a plus is due to the [standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) which your form is using, so I don't think this is possible.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: @Quentin: Oops... I thought my answer was evident. I have edited it accordingly, however. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible (you just have to rebuild the entire form submission logic in JS before you can modify it).