# Equivalent to Rack::Utils.build_query that uses %20 (instead of +) for spaces

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a function that converts a hash into a query string. I know `Rack::Utils.build_query` but it use `+` for spaces.

Comment: Why does it matter if you use `+` or `%20`? They should be interpreted as the same thing when decoding.

Comment: Think of an api endpoint that requires you to compute a signature based on the query string.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you need to parse the URL, standardize it (so that `?a=b&c=d` and `?c=d&a=b` really do come out the same), and then put it back together? Then your "put it back together" step would standardize on `+` or `%20` for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`build_query` makes use of `Rack::Utils.escape`, which replaces spaces with + characters. You could add a version of build_query that makes use of `Rack::Utils.escape_path`, e.g.

```
module Rack::Utils
  def your_build_query(params)
    params.map { |k, v|
      if v.class == Array
        build_query(v.map { |x| [k, x] })
      else
        v.nil? ? escape_path(k) : "#{escape_path(k)}=#{escape_path(v)}"
      end
    }.join("&")
  end
end
```

But all `escape_path(s)` does is `escape(s).gsub('+', '%20')`, so you could just call `Rack::Utils.build_query(s).gsub('+', '%20')`.

Comment: It surely works but essentially it does `str.gsub(' ', '+').gsub('+', '%20')` which it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`URI::encode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form)? It's built into Ruby.

From the documentation:

```
URI.encode_www_form([["q", "ruby"], ["lang", "en"]])
#=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form("q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en")
#=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form("q" => ["ruby", "perl"], "lang" => "en")
#=> "q=ruby&q=perl&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form([["q", "ruby"], ["q", "perl"], ["lang", "en"]])
#=> "q=ruby&q=perl&lang=en"
```

As for the question of using `%20` or `+`, see "[When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20)".

Comment: `URI.encode_www_form` is not different from `Rack::Utils.build_query`. "This method doesn’t convert *, -, ., 0-9, A-Z, _, a-z, but does convert SP (ASCII space) to + and converts others to %XX."