# Trying to encode a string using PHP

Tags: php

I am having a string `United States` and i need to use this like `United%20States`.
For this i am using 
`urlencode("United States");`
But, it is giving me the result as `United+States`.
Please help me in getting me my output as `United%20States`

Thanks!

Comment: Not answering your question, but I'd suggest avoiding the %20 and using "-" instead. Especially if this is part of an url, people have a much easier time reading - than %20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rawurlencode` in this case (http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You want [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), which

> Encodes the given string according to [» RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html).

Note that [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) says:

> This differs from the [» RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986) encoding (see [rawurlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.

See also:

- [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rawurlencode to achieve it-
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using rawurlencode
Refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
<?php echo rawurlencode("United States"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php // str_rot13() example $string = 'Encoding and Decoding Encrypted PHP Code'; $encoded = str_rot13($string); $decoded = str_rot13(str_rot13($string)); echo $encoded ."\n"; echo $decoded; ?>`