# Routing with space replacement in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to link to `/member/:name`. I'm using this line in `routes.rb`:

```
match 'member/:id', :to => "members#show", :as => :show_member, :via => :get
```

and this in the model:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

Next, I want to link to a the name represented as a string that has white spaces. I want to replace the white spaces with `+` (plus) or something else more readable than standard `%20` replacement.

I could handle these replacements (from space to `+`, and from `+` to space) in a method, but I was wondering if there is a better way of handling this.

Comment: If i want my url to be with +, instead of %20, how would i tell the browser that? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@screenmutt is right of course. However, have you tried returning the desired string from `to_param`? I'm unsure whether it would URL encode the `+`, but my instinct is that it wouldn't because it's a valid URL character.

```
def to_param
  username.tr(' ', '+')
end
```

Then you'd need to write a finder method that converts the `+` back to a space..

```
def self.from_param(uname)
  find_by_username!(uname.tr('+', ' '))
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems about right on what i want to do. I want to use the plus-sign instead of html-space. (its more pretty :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which was created for this purpose.  If you would like to create it yourself then I would consider adding an attribute to the database to store the value by which you will lookup the user.  As an idea...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :build_url_parameter
  validates_uniqueness_of :url_parameter, :on => :update

  def to_param
    self.url_parameter
  end

  private
    def build_url_parameter
      self.url_parameter = self.name.gsub(/\s+/, '-')
      unless User.where( url_parameter: self.url_parameter ).count.zero?
        self.url_parameter << "-#{self.id}"
      end
      save
    end
end
```

By taking this approach you guarantee that the parameter is unique (which may not otherwise be true of users' names).

Answer (score 0):

Marcus,

This is not something which is standard. Browsers will write `%20` for spaces inside of the URL and `+` for spaces inside of queries.

The only way to convert this would be to do a redirect every time the user searches for a URL with a `%20` in it.

However, I don't think this would be worth the effort. Why violate a standard?

[When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602/1669208)