# Why is requests is adding a part of a list to repeated query URIs?

Tags: python, variables, post, python-requests

I am trying to place a variable into a POST request using the Requests library.  Here is my code:

```
import requests

message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"

split_message = message.split()

initial_request = requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q='.join(split_message[:3]))
print initial_request.content
```

The outcome I am getting is this (which is an error, as it is messing up the URI):

```
No connection adapters were found for 'ifhttp://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=ihttp://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=can't'
```

I would like the request URI to look like this:

```
"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=if i can\'t"
```

What am I missing here?  Is there a better way to pass a variable to the request URI?  I tried using a dictionary as the payload, but I can't place a variable into a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is very counter intuitive, the string is something you *join with* not *join to*.

Examine the following code:

```
>>> x = range(5)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x = [str(c) for c in x]
>>> x
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> "-".join(x)
'0-1-2-3-4'
```

Here the "joiner" (`-`) is inserted between every element in our array, which we've converted to strings using list comprehension.

Here is your code:

```
'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q='.join(split_message[:3])
```

Your joining string is `'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q='` and so this is inserted between every element in the array `split_message[:3]`.

So lets examine whats going on:

```
>>> message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"
>>> split_message = message.split()
>>> split_message
['if', 'i', "can't", 'let', 'it', 'go', 'out', 'of', 'my', 'mind']
>>> split_message[:3]
['if', 'i', "can't"]
```

Here the array is 3 items long, which explains why the output string is:

```
 ifhttp://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=ihttp://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=can't
```

But adding in some line breaks:

```
 if
   http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=
 i
   http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=
 can't'
```

Notice the joining string is inserted twice, which explains why at first glance it just looks like its mucking up the URI.

What you want instead is:

```
request = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q='+"%20".join(split_message[:3])
```

Notice, in the above we `join` using `%20`: like so: `"%20".join(split_message[:3])` and add this the request prefix. Which gives the URL below, with the spaces correctly encoded:

```
"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=if%20i%20can't"
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation on why this is happening.

Comment: @Barnaby If its helpful accepting an answer by clicking the green tick lets other users with similar problems know a particular answer help you solve your particular issue.

Comment: yes, i plan on doing so.  is the %20 a URL code for a space or +?

Comment: @Barnaby Both the `+` and `%20` are legal tokens for escaping a single space ina URI *in the query portion only*. [Generally `%20` is safer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20).

Comment: Please note that you should let Requests encode the query string for you, as per @user2357112's answer.

Comment: @Lukasa I've not used the requests library before, you're probably right. I was just answering what I understood the question to be: "why isn't join working like I think it should"

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Sure. =) That comment was intended more for Barnaby than for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
initial_request = requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=' +
                               ' '.join(split_message[:3]))
```

`s.join(seq)` sticks together the elements of `seq` with the string `s` stuck between them. For example, `'a'.join('bcd') == 'bacad'`. Note that your desired string probably isn't what you really should be sending; you should probably use `+` instead of spaces. The requests module can handle url parameter encoding for you:

```
params = {'q': ' '.join(split_message[:3])}
initial_request = requests.get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track',
                               params=params)
```

Comment: `+` only works for encoding spaces in the query part, not the rest of the URI. `%20` is generally safer.