# jsp unable to replace %20 with space?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem I am trying  to make a link between the jsp files (in WebContent) and the java files in Java Resources directory .
In the Html page URL I am unable to replace %20 with space.

`<form action="<%= (request.getContextPath() + "/Java Resources/src/utilities").replaceAll("%20", " ") %>/Login.java" method="post" >`

Comment: Yes seems you cant, browser again add %20. Normally browser added %20 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20 Check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to replace the `%20` with a space in the `action` attribute; they mean the same thing, but `%20` is the normalized form.

I suspect you're seeing this because of the way you're looking at it.

Your `replaceAll` works ([example](http://ideone.com/shixWW)). But literal spaces in URLs are generally a bad idea (I think with `http` URLs they're invalid, in fact, but I'd have to check the RFC). `%20` is what they're replaced with in URL-encoding. So my suspicion is that although you're successfully replacing the `%20` with a space, when you use the form, the browser is showing you the normalized form (with the `%20` instead).