# Can I use a converter to format the output of an object within any EL expression in JSF?

Tags: jsf, formatting, converters

Class:

```
public class Booking {
    String foo1;
    String foo2;
}
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Booking.class)
public class BookingDisplayConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)     {        
        Booking booking = (Booking) arg2;        
        return (booking.getFoo1() +" ("+ booking.getFoo2() +")");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

This works fine:

```
<h:outputText value="#{ViewReservation.booking}"/>
```

This does not (it uses toString()):

```
<h:commandButton value="Email" onclick="location.href = 'mailto:me@example.com?subject=Reservation: #{ViewReservation.booking})'; return false;"/>
```

Is there a way to get the converter to work in the 2nd example?

EDIT: I'm aware that I could create a ApplicationBean scoped formatter that could do something like **#{ApplicationBean.formatBooking(booking)}** but I'm looking for something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to get the converter to work in the 2nd example?*

Not via the standard JSF API.

JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has however an [`<o:param>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param) for exactly this purpose, extending the standard `<f:param>` with support for a converter. However, this works only in cases where a `<f:param>` would be applicable, which isn't the case in an `onclick` attribute.

If it's affordable to replace the `<h:commandButton>` by a `<h:outputLink>`, then you could use it as follows:

```
<h:outputLink value="mailto:me@example.com">
    Email
    <o:param name="subject" value="#{viewReservation.booking}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

You can always throw in some CSS to make it to look like a button.

Noted should be that you should in first place really be using a `<f:param>` for this, because it also URL-encodes the values for usage in query string. E.g. the `:` should be encoded as `%3A`. Inlining an EL expression won't do that and may potentially malform the URL or even the JavaScript syntax if it contains quotes and such.

Also noted should be that the `<h:commandButton>` with a `return false;` is after all a fairly clumsy choice for the job. You'd better have grabbed `<h:button>` if you really needed a dead button.

Comment: Yes, this could be an acceptable answer but...when I try it, it doesn't seem to encode spaces properly (it puts a + sign in place instead of %20).  Should this be able to handle that?

Comment: Here is the URL your code produces: mailto:me@example.com?subject=1064+%28asdfqwer%29

Comment: That's indeed what `URLEncoder` does. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20/

Comment: It actually looks like it is a JSF issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1019 .  Fixed in JSF 2.2.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck using JSF 2.1 for the near future.  Will mark this as the answer though.

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem? In your specific case you're encoding an URL query string parameter, not the URL path. The `+` in a query string parameter is perfectly valid. See also the link in my previous comment. The `+` is only not valid in an URL path like `http://example.com/foo+bar`, which should indeed have been `http://example.com/foo%20bar`.

Comment: The problem is, when you click a mailto link encoded using params, it converts spaces to + signs and mail clients do not re-interpret the + back to spaces.  They do re-interpret %20.  I mean...they changed the encoding behavior in 2.2 because of this, right?

Comment: The issue is about spaces in URL paths (where `+` is indeed invalid), not in URL query strings (where `+` is valid). Which mail client exactly has problems with it?

Comment: Specifically, Thunderbird.  Here is where I found the bug referenced: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2235427?tstart=0 .  User had same issue I did.  BTW, you may be technically correct throughout this entire conversation.  I'm not an encoding "expert".  I just want my mailto links to work with spaces :)