# EOF exception in http request

Tags: android, http

i am working on a android app in which i am sending a http request using **HttpURLConnection**. my Url contains some space bars. so it got an error `java.io.EOFException`

If i replace all the space bars " " into "_" the error will be resolve.

so is their any way to stop the error or can resolve it using any special escape character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing it with "%20" which is the URL encoding for space.

This will be your guide:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116989/1593883