# How to force %20 instead of + in System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: c#, .net

I need to encode a URL in a class library assembly where I don't want to reference System.Web. The URL contains several spaces

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quote where  symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL")&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

When I use System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode() the spaces are replaced with "+" which doesn't work. I need them to be replaced with %20

How can I achieve this without referencing System.Web?

Comment: ` "+" which doesn't work`  Why not?  `+` and `%20` should be interpreted the same way by any code that can correctly interpret URL encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20

Comment: The Yahoo Finance query language doesn't interpret the "+" as equivalent to a space (%20). I tried the URL manually both ways and with the "+" it doesn't work.

Comment: The URL you have provided returns a valid JSON response with + or %20 (or indeed spaces..)

Comment: @sturatd - JSON is only a small part of the use of UrlEncoding.  I am trying to create a mailto tag providing both subject line and body.  The WebUtility.UrlEncode is creating a URL with + instead of %20 and as such my mail program displays the plus signs.  It does not display the %20.  Uri.EscapeUriString does not escape forward slashes correctly.  The question by the OP is very much valid and has not yet been answered.

Answer (score 24):

You could try [`Uri.EscapeUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx) from `System` assembly, which escapes a URI string. For the string from the question it returns:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%253A%252F%252Fdatatables.org%252Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

Answer (score 9):

`Uri.EscapeDataString()` is better for you purpose since `Uri.EscapeUriString()` can skip some special characters

Answer (score 0):

HttpUtility.ParseQueryString will work as long as you are in a web app or don't mind including a dependency on System.Web. Another way to do this is:

```
NameValueCollection queryParameters = new NameValueCollection();
string[] querySegments = queryString.Split('&');
foreach(string segment in querySegments)
{
   string[] parts = segment.Split('=');
   if (parts.Length > 0)
   {
      string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
      string val = parts[1].Trim();

      queryParameters.Add(key, val);
   }
}
```