# How to UrlEncode symbols ( and )

Tags: c#, urlencode

I use System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(myString) to UrlEncode string and get encoded string in uppercase tags after encoding (I found solution [.net UrlEncode - lowercase problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918019/net-urlencode-lowercase-problem)). But problem what left for me ar ( and ) encoding. In this case both symbols left uncoded when I need %28 and %29 code instead them. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you will just have to do the replacement yourself as [shown here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484829/how-to-force-20-instead-of-in-system-net-webutility-urlencode). Interestingly, Notepad++ MIME Tools plugin has a "full urlencode" feature that does it.

Comment: I used this: myString = myString.Replace("(", "%28").Replace(")", "%29");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this:

```
myString = myString.Replace("(", "%28").Replace(")", "%29");
```