# encode_www_form converting space to + instead of %20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create http parameters from a hash I have using Ruby on Rails, I have tried  using `URI.encode_www_form(params)` , but this is not generating the parameters correctly.

Below is the hash I have

```
params['Name'.to_sym] = 'Nia Kun'
params['AddressLine1'.to_sym] = 'Address One'
params['City'.to_sym] = 'City Name'
```

`This method converts space to +`, what I want is it to `convert space with %20`

I am getting `"Name=Nia+Kun&AddressLine1=Address+One&City=City+Name"` but I need this spaces to be converted to %20

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this:

```
URI.encode_www_form(params).gsub("+", "%20")
```

if that is really what you need.

See also [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20) why it does it in this way.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `URI::escape`.

```
URI::escape "this big string"
=> "this%20big%20string"
```

EDIT

Bringing it all together:

- You don't need to convert to symbols for your `params`, rails is smart and knows about `with_indifferent_access`. Strings and symbols will both work.
- Your code would look like this:

.

```
name = params['Name']# = 'Nia Kun'
address_one = params['AddressLine1']# = 'Address One'
city = params['City']# = 'City Name'

URI::encode "http://www.example.com?name=#{name}&address_one=#{address_one}&city=#{city}"

#=> "http://www.example.com?name=Nia%20Kun&address_one=Address%20One&city=City%20Name"
```

Comment: where in the above code do i need to use URI::escape, i just want space to ve converted to %20 not entire URL

Comment: Hello max, its not working and converting every spacial character in url to %20 or %40

Comment: I'd be curious as to what characters you are looking to escape/not escape and why? URI::encode (or its alias, [URI::escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html)) precisely replaces all unsafe chars with codes. If you are not sure why something works, there is a bunch of reference out there - wikipedia has a [great article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_in_a_URI) on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom method. Something like this:

```
p = {x: 'some word', y: 'hello there'}
URI.encode p.to_a.map {|inner| inner.join('=') }.join('&')
# "x=some%20word&y=hello%20there"
```

So basically you flatten params to array of array, then transform them to url string, then encode it.

EDIT:

Final solution will look like this:

```
def encode_url(params)
  URI.encode params.to_a.map {|inner| inner.join('=')}.join('&')
end

encode_url(my_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSUB](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
myString.gsub(" ", "%20")
```

Quoting the [doc](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form_component):

> This method doesn't convert *, -, ., 0-9, A-Z, _, a-z, but does convert SP (ASCII space) to + and converts others to %XX.

Comment: is it the only way? i thought i am not using URI.encode_www_form properly

Comment: i see that this is the only way, but its very strange that this is such a basic thing i thought there should be a built in function to do this, but i may also be wrong since i am a beginer