# % character encoding with URIEncoding setting on Tomcat

Tags: special-characters, urlencode

Is % character encoded to '`%25'` With `URIEncoding="utf-8"` setting on server.xml?

I have a file named `abc%.wav` on the server and try to access it with hyperlink, but the server response 404 not found.

I encoded the file name in the java class file, then it worked fine.

So I am curious whether % character is encoded with the setting above or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)

Comment: I'm assuming you have access to the server, so why don't you just change encoding and try it out? What happens if you access the file using abc%25.waw?