# Spacing are replaced with + when i output a result

Tags: jquery

when i try to do an output for this function, it replaces the space to a + sign. can someone help me please

Picture Containing the issue that i'm facing:

[image]

```
function weightdifference(){
        var weight;
        var dreamweight;
        var calDifference;

        weight = parseFloat(document.bmiform.weight.value);
        dreamweight = parseFloat(document.bmiform.dreamweight.value);


        if (dreamweight > weight){

        calDifference = (dreamweight - weight)/0.064;
        return "You need" +calDifference+ "to your ideal weight";
        }

        else if (dreamweight < weight){

            calDifference = (weight - dreamweight)/0.064;
            return "You need" +calDifference+ "to your ideal weight";
        }

    }

    function results(){
                   var calDifference = weightdifference();
                   var Difference = calDifference;
                   document.bmiform.Difference.value = Difference;
                   document.bmiform.submit();
       }
```

Results Page

```
 var difference;
 difference = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["Difference"]);

     Days to Target Weight: <script>document.write(difference)</script><br>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's `getUrlVars`? How is the data it gives you encoded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're using PHP server-side and using `urlencode` to encode your parameters. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20) is why I'm guessing that.

If you can change the server side, change it to use `rawurlencode` instead.

If you can't, and you **know** `+` will be encoded (e.g., to `%2b`) in what you receive, then you can safely do this:

```
difference = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["Difference"].replace(/\+/g, "%20"));
```

There, we're replacing `+` with the standard `%20` sequence for a space, and then letting `decodeURIComponent` do its job.

But if you can, update how the data's being encoded.

Comment: thanks!! I have change the method to getlocalstorage function and it works! :D