# Properly Encode spray.http.Uri.Path?

Tags: scala, spray

I'd like to properly URL encode: `http://a.b.c/apis/POST /foo/bar` where `POST /foo/bar` should be encoded as: `POST%20%2Ffoo%2Fbar`.

Here's what I tried:

```
scala> import spray.http._
import spray.http._

scala> val base = Uri("http:/a.b.c")
base: spray.http.Uri = http:///a.b.c

scala> val path = Uri.Path("/apis/GET /foo/bar")
path: spray.http.Uri.Path = /apis/GET%20/foo/bar

scala> base.withPath(path)
res0: spray.http.Uri = http:///apis/GET%20/foo/bar
```

But, the above shows `/foo/bar` as additional path fields, rather than as `GET%20%2Ffoo%2Fbar`.

In addition, I tried:

```
scala> Uri.Path("/apis/" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("GET /foo/bar", "UTF-8"))
res1: spray.http.Uri.Path = /apis/GET+%2Ffoo%2Fbar
```

However, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602/409976, a space should be encoded as `%20` in the path part (as I understand). In addition, when using a `+` rather than `%20`, the web service that I'm accessing returns an HTTP-500.

Comment: The operation is called URL encoding. Spray creators should have given this a proper name in their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> Uri("http:/a.b.c").path / "apis" / "GET /foo/bar"
res0: spray.http.Uri.Path = /a.b.c/apis/GET%20%2Ffoo%2Fbar
```