# How to encode String with spaces "my string has space" to "my%20string%20has%20space" in java?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have tried with :-

1) URLEncoder. 
---it gave me something like this "my+string+has+space".

2)Charset. 
-- it was not working. with "UTF-8" and "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Why not just `String.replace`?

Comment: What's wrong with #1? That is a perfectly valid URL encoding. Sure, `%20` is an *alternate* way to do it, but that doesn't make `+` any less valid.

Comment: @SantiBailors right now I am using String.replace but is it valid?.

Comment: @Andreas Our UAA(user authentication and Authorization) was not accepting "+" as properly encoded value.

Comment: I don't see why not, but I don't know what's your concern about `String.replace` being "valid" or not. Can you specify ? The only possibility I can think of is if in your case you need not to replace inside some delimiters. BTW, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2678551/2814308) and the one linked from its only comment might give you useful info on the subject.

Comment: If your string is to be used as a URL and your concern is about the encoding of the other characters that also need encoding, you could consider using `URLEncoder` and then replacing all the `+` with `%20`.