# How to fetch get parameter

Tags: php

Here is my url:

> http://localhost/store/index.php/validate_email?id=K73/N7gAtqElUW0GQQ6lhelTSHIoKiP/JrTbxX0XZNgw8VKuib5fr1Y2zjRj4iB38s2iVXssuF+PbEA+swwyfA==&code=f3BHyZTAeZzv+++fK5AWSdsNMKjfyAJAzyMzVHucc/WMYtWPK8hR3cDRdOD+NKByUl6mcgYDVeKWFgjYwuObpzpQ==

Now when I get parameters using `$_GET` then it excludes all `+` sign.

```
 Array ( [id] => K73/N7gAtqElUW0GQQ6lhelTSHIoKiP/JrTbxX0XZNgw8VKuib5fr1Y2zjRj4iB38s2iVXssuF PbEA swwyfA== [code] => f3BHyZTAeZzv fK5AWSdsNMKjfyAJAzyMzVHucc/WMYtWPK8hR3cDRdOD NKByUl6mcgYDVeKWFgjYwuObpzpQ== )
```

My ID in URL is:

```
K73/N7gAtqElUW0GQQ6lhelTSHIoKiP/JrTbxX0XZNgw8VKuib5fr1Y2zjRj4iB38s2iVXssuF+PbEA+swwyfA==
```

But what I am getting is:

```
K73/N7gAtqElUW0GQQ6lhelTSHIoKiP/JrTbxX0XZNgw8VKuib5fr1Y2zjRj4iB38s2iVXssuF PbEA swwyfA== (no + symbol)
```

same case for code.

Comment: That's a beautiful URL, but how are you parsing it and what exactly is not working?

Comment: i am using directly $_GET['id']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602/4248328  (+ converted to space, i hope you have that issue)

Comment: That's because you haven't encoded your URL. You need to use `urlencode`

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#refsect1-function.urldecode-notes):

> The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded.

Still, if you want as the URL, [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) manually:

```
echo urlencode($_GET['id']);
```

This gives:

```
K73%2FN7gAtqElUW0GQQ6lhelTSHIoKiP%2FJrTbxX0XZNgw8VKuib5fr1Y2zjRj4iB38s2iVXssuF+PbEA+swwyfA%3D%3D
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%2B` instead of `+`. I've tested.