# Remove '%20' from URL - React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-v4

I'm using react and I came across a problem, albeit an aesthetic problem and not a functional one.

I am generating `react-route`s from an API of names. The route works fine, but as the names have spaces, they appear in the url as: `example.com/lookup/David%20Attenborough`

Example: `<Link to='{/lookup/' + props.data.name}>{props.data.name}</Link>`

Is there a clever way I can remove the spaces: `example.com/lookup/DavidAttenborough` or even with `+` or `-` to replace spaces without losing the structural integrity of `react-router`.

Comment: you could do something like this: props.data.name.split(' ').join(''); Or use regex

Comment: You could use .split(' ').join('-') on props.data.name, but I'm not sure if your router will break

Comment: @floor you beat me too it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)

Comment: It's called a slug, you can do this with [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify) or [others](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=slug). What do you mean by _losing the structural integrity of react-router_?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `+` is not valid as an encoding for spaces in the path, only in the query string. See [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20) and  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2407

You cannot do what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for Putting (- or +) in the url
example

```
let name = props.data.name;
name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
const url = `/lookup/${name}

<Link to={url}>{props.data.name}</Link>
```

you can either add + or -

Comment: on some browser this will change only the first occurance of %20, try to add a loop (while(name.contains("%20") ... replace) or a test to use replaceAll if supported

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<Link to={`/lookup/${props.data.name.split(` `).join(`-`).toLowerCase()}`}>{props.data.name}</Link>
```