# Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API Decoding + (%2B) As Space

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Given the following method in a controller for a ASP.NET Web API:

```
[HttpGet]
[ApiRoute("resource/{id}/end-point)]
public IHttpActionResult MethodName (int id, string clientTimeZone)
{
     ...
}
```

Whenever I submit a GET request to http://localhost:5684/api/v1/resource/1/end-point?client_timezone=%2B0500 clientTimezone is passed in to clientTimeZone as %2B0500 and it parses the encoded '+' sign into a space character. Why can't ASP.NET decode +'s from the URI?

In the header I have "ContentType = application/json" and a bearer token

I am trying to get "+0500" into my method but it is turning into " 0500"

Comment: Are you sure %2B is being sent and not +?

Comment: Yes %2B is being sent in, not +

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when consuming the api? This will treat a '+' character as a space when used in your URL.

More details here:
[When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20/)

Try changing your `Content-Type` to `application/json` instead and see if parameter binding behaves as expected.

Comment: I went ahead and tried changing the content type, that didn't work