# How to form a URI in Ruby with %20 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to form a url like

```
http://www.google.com?name=john%20doe
```

using Ruby.

I have

```
u = URI::HTTP.build(host: 'www.google.com', query: { name: 'john doe' }.to_query)
```

`u.to_s` gives me `http://www.google.com?name=john+doe`.

The whitespace in `john doe` is replaced with `+` because

```
{ name: 'john doe' }.to_query
```

returns `name=john+doe` (to_query is a Rails addition I believe)

I want `%20` instead of `+`.  How do I achieve this easily?

I'm aware that `URI::encode` does encode a whitespace to a `%20`, but I wonder if there's a better way than converting a hash to a string and then sending it through URI::encode.

Comment: Both + and %20 are valid in the query string portion as spaces, so what is being generated is correct according to the RFC.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602

Answer (score 1):

Use: `url_encode('john doe')` [Docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/ERB/Util/url_encode)